# When should I use arrow functions in ECMAScript 6?

Tags: javascript, lambda, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-harmony, arrow-functions

With `() => {}` and `function () {}` we are getting two very similar ways to write functions in ES6. In other languages lambda functions often distinguish themselves by being anonymous, but in ECMAScript any function can be anonymous. Each of the two types have unique usage domains (namely when `this` needs to either be bound explicitly or explicitly not be bound). Between those domains there are a vast number of cases where either notation will do.

Arrow functions in ES6 have at least two limitations:

- Don't work with `new` and cannot be used when creating `prototype`
- Fixed `this` bound to scope at initialisation

These two limitations aside, arrow functions could theoretically replace regular functions almost anywhere. What is the right approach using them in practice? Should arrow functions be used e.g.:

- "everywhere they work", i.e. everywhere a function does not have to be agnostic about the `this` variable and we are not creating an object.
- only "everywhere they are needed", i.e. event listeners, timeouts, that need to be bound to a certain scope
- with 'short' functions, but not with 'long' functions
- only with functions that do not contain another arrow function

I am looking for a guideline to selecting the appropriate function notation in the future version of ECMAScript. The guideline will need to be clear, so that it can be taught to developers in a team, and to be consistent so that it does not require constant refactoring back and forth from one function notation to another.

<sub>The question is directed at people who have thought about code style in the context of the upcoming ECMAScript 6 (Harmony) and who have already worked with the language.</sub>

Comment: You consider `Fixed this bound to scope at initialisation` as a limitation?

Comment: It is an advantage, but it can also be a limitation if you plan to reuse the function outside the original context. For instance when adding a function to an class dynamically via Object.prototype. What I mean by 'limitation' is that changing the value of `this` is something  you can do with regular functions but not with arrow functions.

Comment: Honestly I think coding style guidelines are rather opinionated. Don't get me wrong, I think they are important, but there is not a single guideline that is suitable for everyone.

Comment: I don't think `Fixed this bound to scope at initialisation` is a limitation. :) Take a look at this article:

http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html

Comment: `Fixed this bound to scope at initialisation` also known as lexical binding

Comment: @thefourtheye, 
"limitation" here means "limitation because a dumb automatic code translator couldn't blindly replace one with another and assume that everything will run as expected".

Comment: Related post - [Are 'Arrow Functions' and 'Functions' equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/465053)

Answer (score 380):

A while ago our team migrated all its code (a mid-sized AngularJS app) to JavaScript compiled using <strike>Traceur</strike> [Babel](http://babeljs.io). I'm now using the following rule of thumb for functions in ES6 and beyond:

- Use `function` in the global scope and for `Object.prototype` properties.
- Use `class` for object constructors.
- Use `=>` everywhere else.

Why use arrow functions almost everywhere?

1. Scope safety: When arrow functions are used consistently, everything is guaranteed to use the same `thisObject` as the root. If even a single standard function callback is mixed in with a bunch of arrow functions there's a chance the scope will become messed up.
2. Compactness: Arrow functions are easier to read and write. (This may seem opinionated so I will give a few examples further on.)
3. Clarity: When almost everything is an arrow function, any regular `function` immediately sticks out for defining the scope. A developer can always look up the next-higher `function` statement to see what the `thisObject` is.

Why always use regular functions on the global scope or module scope?

1. To indicate a function that should not access the `thisObject`.
2. The `window` object (global scope) is best addressed explicitly.
3. Many `Object.prototype` definitions live in the global scope (think `String.prototype.truncate`, etc.) and those generally have to be of type `function` anyway. Consistently using `function` on the global scope helps avoid errors.
4. Many functions in the global scope are object constructors for old-style class definitions.
5. Functions can be named<sup>1</sup>. This has two benefits: (1) It is less awkward to write`function foo(){}` than `const foo = () => {}` — in particular outside other function calls. (2) The function name shows in stack traces. While it would be tedious to name every internal callback, naming all the public functions is probably a good idea.
6. Function declarations are [*hoisted*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Function_declaration_hoisting), (meaning they can be accessed before they are declared), which is a useful attribute in a static utility function.

#### Object constructors

Attempting to instantiate an arrow function throws an exception:

```
var x = () => {};
new x(); // TypeError: x is not a constructor
```

One key advantage of functions over arrow functions is therefore that functions double as object constructors:

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

However, the functionally identical<sup>2</sup> ECMAScript Harmony [draft class definition](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:maximally_minimal_classes) is almost as compact:

```
class Person {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I expect that use of the former notation will eventually be discouraged. The object constructor notation may still be used by some for simple anonymous object factories where objects are programmatically generated, but not for much else.

Where an object constructor is needed one should consider converting the function to a `class` as shown above. The syntax works with anonymous functions/classes as well.

#### Readability of arrow functions

The probably best argument for sticking to regular functions - scope safety be damned - would be that arrow functions are less readable than regular functions. If your code is not functional in the first place, then arrow functions may not seem necessary, and when arrow functions are not used consistently they look ugly.

ECMAScript has changed quite a bit since ECMAScript 5.1 gave us the functional `Array.forEach`, `Array.map` and all of these functional programming features that have us use functions where *for* loops would have been used before. Asynchronous JavaScript has taken off quite a bit. ES6 will also ship a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) object, which means even more anonymous functions. There is no going back for functional programming. In functional JavaScript, arrow functions are preferable over regular functions.

Take for instance this (particularly confusing) piece of code<sup>3</sup>:

```
function CommentController(articles) {
    this.comments = [];

    articles.getList()
        .then(articles => Promise.all(articles.map(article => article.comments.getList())))
        .then(commentLists => commentLists.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b)));
        .then(comments => {
            this.comments = comments;
        })
}
```

The same piece of code with regular functions:

```
function CommentController(articles) {
    this.comments = [];

    articles.getList()
        .then(function (articles) {
            return Promise.all(articles.map(function (article) {
                return article.comments.getList();
            }));
        })
        .then(function (commentLists) {
            return commentLists.reduce(function (a, b) {
                return a.concat(b);
            });
        })
        .then(function (comments) {
            this.comments = comments;
        }.bind(this));
}
```

While any one of the arrow functions can be replaced by a standard function, there would be very little to gain from doing so. Which version is more readable? I would say the first one.

I think the question whether to use arrow functions or regular functions will become less relevant over time. Most *functions* will either become class methods, which make away with the `function` keyword, or they will become classes. Functions will remain in use for patching classes through the `Object.prototype`. In the mean time I suggest reserving the `function` keyword for anything that should really be a class method or a class.

---

#### Notes

1. Named arrow functions have been [deferred in the ES6 specification](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:arrow_function_syntax#deferred). They might still be added a future version.
2. According to the draft specification, *"Class declarations/expressions create a constructor function/prototype pair exactly as for function declarations"* as long as a class does not use the `extend` keyword. A minor difference is that class declarations are constants, whereas function declarations are not.
3. Note on blocks in single statement arrow functions: I like to use a block wherever an arrow function is called for the side effect alone (e.g., assignment). That way it is clear that the return value can be discarded.

Comment: The other time you would want to use `function` is when you don't want `this` to be bound, right? My most common scenario for this is events, where you may want `this` to refer to the object (usually DOM node) that triggered the event.

Comment: @Brett yes, an unbound `this` object is the general case for using `function`. In events the information from `this` would also be in the event object (`event.currentTarget` for DOM events), but `this` may be a convenient accessor if you do not need it for something else.

Comment: Thinking about it a bit more I think I'd prefer to have a bound `this` for events and tap those extra few keystrokes to access `event.currentTarget` as you suggest. Thanks for your question and answer.

Comment: I actually think in example 3, the regular functions are more readable. Even non-programmers could divine what is happening. With the arrows, you need to know exactly how they work to understand that example. 

Maybe more newlines would help the arrow example, but I don't know. Just my 2 cents but arrows make me cringe (but I haven't used them yet, so I may be converted soon.)

Comment: @Spencer that is a fair point. From my own experience, `=>` ends up looking better with time. I doubt that non-programmers would feel very differently about the two examples. If you're writing ES2016 code, you're not normally going to end up using this many arrow functions either. In this example, using async/await and an array comprehension, you would end up with just one arrow function in the `reduce()` call.

Comment: @Spencer, It all depends on which one you are used to.

Comment: I completely agree with Spencer that regular functions are far more readable in that example.

Comment: Am I missing something, or doesn't the comment-setting bit have different behavior in the two examples (different value of `this`)?

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon it depends on the implementation. I will add a .bind() to clarify.

Comment: The above two comments and revision #11 on this answer demonstrate how uncertainty may arise from directly referencing `this` and using arrows. If `then` bound `this` specially, the code before that revision (without `bind`) could have also been correct, and the choice between `() => {}` and `function` would depend on more than readability. That is the type of uncertainty I attempt to avert with the guideline in my answer.

Comment: @Jackson I think you misunderstood the discussion. There was uncertainty with the solution that did not use arrows.

Comment: The uncertainty was spread over both solutions; it wasn't clear which solution used `this` correctly. Either the one with arrows was right, and `this` should have been a `CommentsController`, or the one with `function` was right, and `this` should have been whatever `then` bound it to (maybe `articles` or something else).

Comment: Good answer, thx! personally I also use arrows in the global scope as much as possible. This leaves me with almost no 'function'. To me a 'function' in the code means a special case that needs to stick out and be carefully considered.

Comment: @lyschoening Is `this` the same as `eventTarget` when using delegate event binding? I thought `this` would be in the element context the event is bound to while `eventTarget` is in the context of the element that triggered the event.

Comment: It is possible that the folks that think the regular functions are more readable are probably liking the extra whitespace. Perhaps the `=>` example could be indented in the same way for an equivalent comparison? Although I still think the `=>` example in its current form is quite readable.

Comment: Just throwing in my two cents here, after 8 years now of arrow functions I still think they are ugly, unreadable, and serve no real useful purpose aside from fewer keystrokes which terser is going to remove for you anyways later.

Comment: I guess readability is a lot about personal preference. I prefer to have the keyword `function` and `this` protected by default so I mostly use the function syntax and arrow function syntax only when I want to "leak" the `this` from the context to the lambda function. And that's only because I find arrow function notation more readable than `bind()`. For many cases, having e.g. `const self = this; .... self.comments = comments` is more explicit about the *intent* of the code than using `bind()` or arrow functions.

Answer (score 91):

According to [the proposal](http://tc39wiki.calculist.org/es6/arrow-functions/), arrows aimed "to address and resolve several common pain points of traditional function expressions". They intended to improve matters by binding `this` lexically and offering terse syntax.

However,

- One cannot consistently bind `this` lexically
- Arrow function syntax is delicate and ambiguous

Therefore, arrow functions create opportunities for confusion and errors, and should be excluded from a JavaScript programmer's vocabulary, replaced with `function` exclusively.

#### Regarding lexical `this`

`this` is problematic:

```
function Book(settings) {
    this.settings = settings;
    this.pages = this.createPages();
}
Book.prototype.render = function () {
    this.pages.forEach(function (page) {
        page.draw(this.settings);
    }, this);
};
```

Arrow functions intend to fix the problem where we need to access a property of `this` inside a callback. There are already several ways to do that: One could assign `this` to a variable, use `bind`, or use the third argument available on the `Array` aggregate methods. Yet arrows seem to be the simplest workaround, so the method could be refactored like this:

```
this.pages.forEach(page => page.draw(this.settings));
```

However, consider if the code used a library like jQuery, whose methods bind `this` specially. Now, there are two `this` values to deal with:

```
Book.prototype.render = function () {
    var book = this;
    this.$pages.each(function (index) {
        var $page = $(this);
        book.draw(book.currentPage + index, $page);
    });
};
```

We must use `function` in order for `each` to bind `this` dynamically. We can't use an arrow function here.

Dealing with multiple `this` values can also be confusing, because it's hard to know which `this` an author was talking about:

```
function Reader() {
    this.book.on('change', function () {
        this.reformat();
    });
}
```

Did the author actually intend to call `Book.prototype.reformat`? Or did he forget to bind `this`, and intend to call `Reader.prototype.reformat`? If we change the handler to an arrow function, we will similarly wonder if the author wanted the dynamic `this`, yet chose an arrow because it fit on one line:

```
function Reader() {
    this.book.on('change', () => this.reformat());
}
```

One may pose: "Is it exceptional that arrows could sometimes be the wrong function to use? Perhaps if we only rarely need dynamic `this` values, then it would still be okay to use arrows most of the time."

But ask yourself this: "Would it be 'worth it' to debug code and find that the result of an error was brought upon by an 'edge case?'" I'd prefer to avoid trouble not just most of the time, but 100% of the time.

There is a better way: Always use `function` (so `this` can always be dynamically bound), and always reference `this` via a variable. Variables are lexical and assume many names. Assigning `this` to a variable will make your intentions clear:

```
function Reader() {
    var reader = this;
    reader.book.on('change', function () {
        var book = this;
        book.reformat();
        reader.reformat();
    });
}
```

Furthermore, *always* assigning `this` to a variable (even when there is a single `this` or no other functions) ensures one's intentions remain clear even after the code is changed.

Also, dynamic `this` is hardly exceptional. jQuery is used on over 50 million websites (as of this writing in February 2016). Here are other APIs binding `this` dynamically:

- Mocha (~120k downloads yesterday) exposes methods for its tests via `this`.
- Grunt (~63k downloads yesterday) exposes methods for build tasks via `this`.
- Backbone (~22k downloads yesterday) defines methods accessing `this`.
- Event APIs (like the DOM's) refer to an `EventTarget` with `this`.
- [Prototypal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) APIs that are patched or extended refer to instances with `this`.

(Statistics via http://trends.builtwith.com/javascript/jQuery and https://www.npmjs.com.)

You are likely to require dynamic `this` bindings already.

A lexical `this` is sometimes expected, but sometimes not; just as a dynamic `this` is sometimes expected, but sometimes not. Thankfully, there is a better way, which always produces and communicates the expected binding.

#### Regarding terse syntax

Arrow functions succeeded in providing a "shorter syntactical form" for functions. But will these shorter functions make you more successful?

Is `x => x * x` "easier to read" than `function (x) { return x * x; }`? Maybe it is, because it's more likely to produce a single, short line of code. According to Dyson's [*The influence of reading speed and line length on the effectiveness of reading from screen*](http://www.academia.edu/421483/The_Influence_of_Reading_Speed_and_Line_Length_on_the_Effectiveness_of_Reading_From_Screen),

> A medium line length (55 characters per line) appears to support effective reading at normal and fast speeds. This produced the highest level of comprehension . . .

Similar justifications are made for the conditional (ternary) operator, and for single-line `if` statements.

However, are you *really writing* the simple mathematical functions [advertised in the proposal](http://tc39wiki.calculist.org/es6/arrow-functions/)? My domains are not mathematical, so my subroutines are rarely so elegant. Rather, I commonly see arrow functions break a column limit, and wrap to another line due to the editor or style guide, which nullifies "readability" by Dyson's definition.

One might pose, "How about just using the short version for short functions, when possible?". But now a stylistic rule contradicts a language constraint: "Try to use the shortest function notation possible, keeping in mind that sometimes only the longest notation will bind `this` as expected." Such conflation makes arrows particularly prone to misuse.

There are numerous issues with arrow function syntax:

```
const a = x =>
    doSomething(x);

const b = x =>
    doSomething(x);
    doSomethingElse(x);
```

Both of these functions are syntactically valid. But `doSomethingElse(x);` is not in the body of `b`. It is just a poorly-indented, top-level statement.

When expanding to the block form, there is no longer an implicit `return`, which one could forget to restore. But the expression may *only* have been intended to produce a side-effect, so who knows if an explicit `return` will be necessary going forward?

```
const create = () => User.create();

const create = () => {
    let user;
    User.create().then(result => {
        user = result;
        return sendEmail();
    }).then(() => user);
};

const create = () => {
    let user;
    return User.create().then(result => {
        user = result;
        return sendEmail();
    }).then(() => user);
};
```

What may be intended as a rest parameter can be parsed as the spread operator:

```
processData(data, ...results => {}) // Spread
processData(data, (...results) => {}) // Rest
```

Assignment can be confused with default arguments:

```
const a = 1;
let x;
const b = x => {}; // No default
const b = x = a => {}; // "Adding a default" instead creates a double assignment
const b = (x = a) => {}; // Remember to add parentheses
```

Blocks look like objects:

```
(id) => id // Returns `id`
(id) => {name: id} // Returns `undefined` (it's a labeled statement)
(id) => ({name: id}) // Returns an object
```

What does this mean?

```
() => {}
```

Did the author intend to create a no-op, or a function that returns an empty object? (With this in mind, should we ever place `{` after `=>`? Should we restrict ourselves to the expression syntax only? That would further reduce arrows' frequency.)

`=>` looks like `<=` and `>=`:

```
x => 1 ? 2 : 3
x <= 1 ? 2 : 3

if (x => 1) {}
if (x >= 1) {}
```

To invoke an arrow function expression immediately, one must place `()` on the outside, yet placing `()` on the inside is valid and could be intentional.

```
(() => doSomething()()) // Creates function calling value of `doSomething()`
(() => doSomething())() // Calls the arrow function
```

Although, if one writes `(() => doSomething()());` with the intention of writing an immediately-invoked function expression, simply nothing will happen.

It's hard to argue that arrow functions are "more understandable" with all the above cases in mind. One *could* learn all the special rules required to utilize this syntax. Is it really worth it?

The syntax of `function` is unexceptionally generalized. To use `function` exclusively means the language itself prevents one from writing confusing code. To write procedures that should be syntactically understood in all cases, I choose `function`.

#### Regarding a guideline

You request a guideline that needs to be "clear" and "consistent." Using arrow functions will eventually result in syntactically-valid, logically-invalid code, with both function forms intertwined, meaningfully and arbitrarily. Therefore, I offer the following:

### Guideline for Function Notation in ES6:

- Always create procedures with `function`.
- Always assign `this` to a variable. Do not use `() => {}`.

Comment: Interesting write up on a functional programmer's view on JavaScript. I am not sure I agree with the private variables argument. IMO few people really need them; those who do will probably also need other contract features and go for a language extension like TypeScript anyway. I can certainly see the appeal of a `self` instead of a this. Your stated arrow function pitfalls are also all valid, and the same standards as on other statements that can go without braces definitely apply here as well; otherwise, I think with your argument one could just as well advocate arrow functions everywhere.

Comment: I revised my thesis to make it more clear that I am arguing against the usage of arrow functions anywhere: "With `this` out of the picture, arrow functions and `function` are almost of equal value; except, due to its stricter syntax, `function` is slightly better. So always use it."

Comment: "Having multiple ways of doing things creates unnecessary vectors for arguments and dissension in the workplace and the language community. It would be better if the language grammar did not allow us to make poor choices." Agree so much. Nice writeup! I think arrow functions are actually a step back. On a different topic, I wish my coworkers would stop trying to turn JavaScript into C# with a series of .prototype definitions. It's disgusting. I should anonymously link your post :)

Comment: @lyschoening, I have added additional arguments in hopes of convincing you of the importance of default privacy and immutability, which besides being important also promote the idea that functions returning objects are better than prototypes, further eliminating the need for `this` and thus dismantling one basis for arrow functions' addition to the language.

Comment: @Jackson It takes a while for people to realize that they should do `() => ({id: 123})` in the last point you added. My experience in converting a few developers to ES6 is that they write `() => { return {id: 123}}` at first. The syntax can be taught. As a Python person, I also dislike the `new` statement, but alas JavaScript is not Python. It's my view that one has to work with what a language provides in order to be productive. A JS developer who cares about immutability and wishes to largely avoid `this` could use e.g. Immutable.js and still enjoy the compactness of the arrow syntax.

Comment: Very well written! Although I disagree with most of your points, it's important to consider the opposite viewpoint.

Comment: Not arrow functions but the weird behavior of `this` is the problem of Javascript. Instead of being implicitly bound, `this` should be passed as an explicit argument.

Comment: @rand Exactly my thoughts, though I would blame jQuery and other libraries for abusing `this` rather than JavaScript for having `this`. It seems like they're just forcing on you a parameter that you can't name.

Comment: "_Always use function (so this can always be dynamically bound), and always reference this via a variable._". **I couldn't disagree more!**

Comment: In some other languages with short-functions the newline is often put after the equal sign: `const a = *newline* x => doSomething(x)`. Doesn't really work well in comments; just paste it somewhere to see what you think.

Comment: Well written, I enjoyed the read. However I can't help but feel the arguments against boil down to preference for historical behavior without introducing new behavior, and simple unfamiliarity with the new. This coming from someone who *hated* the fat arrow syntax at first. But languages should be kept from evolving, and arrow functions do solve problems. You won't be doing yourself a favor (here in 2018) to follow this guide and never use arrow functions.

Comment: @Aaron New is not necessarily better.  I have weighed the advantages of the new way against the old.  What I have found is that the old way should yield correct results more often than the new.  At the cost of being fashionable, I think you will still do yourself a favor by rejecting this feature.

Answer (score 62):

[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) were created to simplify function `scope` and solving the `this` keyword by making it simpler. They utilize the `=>` syntax, which looks like an arrow.

**Note: It does not replace the existing functions. If you replace every function syntax with arrow functions, it's not going to work in all cases.**

Let's have a look at the existing ES5 syntax. If the `this` keyword were inside an object’s method (a function that belongs to an object), what would it refer to?

```
var Actor = {
  name: 'RajiniKanth',
  getName: function() {
     console.log(this.name);
  }
};
Actor.getName();
```

The above snippet would refer to an `object` and print out the name `"RajiniKanth"`. Let's explore the below snippet and see what would this point out here.

```
var Actor = {
  name: 'RajiniKanth',
  movies: ['Kabali', 'Sivaji', 'Baba'],
  showMovies: function() {
   this.movies.forEach(function(movie) {
     alert(this.name + " has acted in " + movie);
   });
  }
};

Actor.showMovies();
```

Now what about if the `this` keyword were inside of `method’s function`?

Here this would refer to `window object` than the `inner function` as its fallen out of `scope`. Because `this`, always references the owner of the function it is in, for this case — since it is now out of scope — the window/global object.

When it is inside of an `object`’s method — the `function`’s owner is the object. Thus the *this* keyword is bound to the object. Yet, when it is inside of a function, either stand alone or within another method, it will always refer to the `window/global` object.

```
var fn = function(){
  alert(this);
}

fn(); // [object Window]
```

There are ways to solve this problem in our ES5 itself. Let us look into that before diving into ES6 arrow functions on how solve it.

Typically you would, create a variable outside of the method’s inner function. Now the `‘forEach’` method gains access to `this` and thus the `object’s` properties and their values.

```
var Actor = {
  name: 'RajiniKanth',
  movies: ['Kabali', 'Sivaji', 'Baba'],
  showMovies: function() {
   var _this = this;
   this.movies.forEach(function(movie) {
     alert(_this.name + " has acted in " + movie);
   });
  }
};

Actor.showMovies();
```

Using `bind` to attach the `this` keyword that refers to the method to the `method’s inner function`.

```
var Actor = {
  name: 'RajiniKanth',
  movies: ['Kabali', 'Sivaji', 'Baba'],
  showMovies: function() {
   this.movies.forEach(function(movie) {
     alert(this.name + " has acted in " + movie);
   }.bind(this));
  }
};

Actor.showMovies();
```

Now with the ES6 arrow function, we can deal with *lexical scoping* issue in a simpler way.

```
var Actor = {
  name: 'RajiniKanth',
  movies: ['Kabali', 'Sivaji', 'Baba'],
  showMovies: function() {
   this.movies.forEach((movie) => {
     alert(this.name + " has acted in " + movie);
   });
  }
};

Actor.showMovies();
```

*Arrow functions* are more like function statements, except that they *bind* the *this* to the *parent scope*. If the *arrow function is in the top scope*, the `this` argument will refer to the *window/global scope*, while an arrow function inside a regular function will have its this argument the same as its outer function.

With *arrow* functions `this` is bound to the enclosing *scope* at creation time and cannot be changed. **The new operator, bind, call, and apply have no effect on this.**

```
var asyncFunction = (param, callback) => {
  window.setTimeout(() => {
  callback(param);
  }, 1);
};

// With a traditional function if we don't control
// the context then can we lose control of `this`.
var o = {
  doSomething: function () {
  // Here we pass `o` into the async function,
  // expecting it back as `param`
  asyncFunction(o, function (param) {
  // We made a mistake of thinking `this` is
  // the instance of `o`.
  console.log('param === this?', param === this);
  });
  }
};

o.doSomething(); // param === this? false
```

In the above example, we lost the control of this. We can solve the above example by using a variable reference of `this` or using `bind`. With ES6, it becomes easier in managing the `this` as its bound to *lexical scoping*.

```
var asyncFunction = (param, callback) => {
  window.setTimeout(() => {
  callback(param);
  }, 1);
};

var o = {
  doSomething: function () {
  // Here we pass `o` into the async function,
  // expecting it back as `param`.
  //
  // Because this arrow function is created within
  // the scope of `doSomething` it is bound to this
  // lexical scope.
  asyncFunction(o, (param) => {
  console.log('param === this?', param === this);
  });
  }
};

o.doSomething(); // param === this? true
```

### When not to use arrow functions

**Inside an object literal.**

```
var Actor = {
  name: 'RajiniKanth',
  movies: ['Kabali', 'Sivaji', 'Baba'],
  getName: () => {
     alert(this.name);
  }
};

Actor.getName();
```

`Actor.getName` is defined with an arrow function, but on invocation it alerts undefined because `this.name` is `undefined` as the context remains to `window`.

It happens because the arrow function binds the context lexically with the `window object`... i.e., the outer scope. Executing `this.name` is equivalent to `window.name`, which is undefined.

#### Object prototype

The same rule applies when defining methods on a `prototype object`. Instead of using an arrow function for defining sayCatName method, which brings an incorrect `context window`:

```
function Actor(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
Actor.prototype.getName = () => {
  console.log(this === window); // => true
  return this.name;
};
var act = new Actor('RajiniKanth');
act.getName(); // => undefined
```

#### Invoking constructors

`this` in a construction invocation is the newly created object. When executing new Fn(), the context of the `constructor Fn` is a new object: `this instanceof Fn === true`.

`this` is setup from the enclosing context, i.e., the outer scope which makes it not assigned to newly created object.

```
var Message = (text) => {
  this.text = text;
};
// Throws "TypeError: Message is not a constructor"
var helloMessage = new Message('Hello World!');
```

#### Callback with dynamic context

Arrow function binds the `context` statically on declaration and is not possible to make it dynamic. Attaching event listeners to DOM elements is a common task in client side programming. An event triggers the handler function with this as the target element.

```
var button = document.getElementById('myButton');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(this === window); // => true
  this.innerHTML = 'Clicked button';
});
```

`this` is window in an arrow function that is defined in the global context. When a click event happens, the browser tries to invoke the handler function with button context, but arrow function does not change its pre-defined context. `this.innerHTML` is equivalent to `window.innerHTML` and has no sense.

You have to apply a function expression, which allows to change this depending on the target element:

```
var button = document.getElementById('myButton');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(this === button); // => true
  this.innerHTML = 'Clicked button';
});
```

When user clicks the button, `this` in the handler function is the button. Thus `this.innerHTML = 'Clicked button'` correctly modifies the button text to reflect the clicked status.

#### References

- *[When 'Not' to Use Arrow Functions](https://dmitripavlutin.com/when-not-to-use-arrow-functions-in-javascript/)*

Comment: Well, I must admit, that _"the best lies in the middle"_. Upvoted for statement, that arrow functions will not cover any possible function use cases. They are really designed to solve only a part of the common problems. Just switch to them completely will be an overkill.

Comment: @DmitriPavlutin: Check my updated post, its a collection of lots of thing... may be i should posted out a reference.

Comment: Your code after the line 'using bind to attach the this keyword that refers to the method to the method’s inner function.' has bugs in it.  Have you tested the rest of your examples?

Comment: The one `using bind to attach the this keyword that refers to the method to the method’s inner function.` has syntax errors.

Comment: Should be `var Actor = {
  name: 'RajiniKanth',
  movies: ['Kabali', 'Sivaji', 'Baba'],
  showMovies: function() {
    this.movies.forEach(function(movie){
      alert(this.name + ' has acted in ' + movie);
    }.bind(this))
  }
}; Actor.showMovies();`

Comment: Great answer! Is there a reason you made the asyncFunction() an arrow function? Or is the only reason because it is cleaner/better readable for you?

Comment: In your last case, with `addEventListener`, you can still get the scope of the click using `event.target` even when using arrow functions. Thoughts?

Answer (score 21):

> **Arrow functions - most widely used ES6 feature so far ...**

Usage: All ES5 functions should be replaced with ES6 arrow functions except in following scenarios:

**Arrow functions should** ***not*** **be used:**

1. When we want function hoisting

   - as arrow functions are anonymous.
2. When we want to use `this`/`arguments` in a function

   - as arrow functions do not have `this`/`arguments` of their own, they depend upon their outer context.
3. When we want to use named function

   - as arrow functions are anonymous.
4. When we want to use function as a `constructor`

   - as arrow functions do not have their own `this`.
5. When we want to add function as a property in object literal and use object in it

   - as we can not access `this` (which should be object itself).

Let us understand some of the variants of arrow functions to understand better:

**Variant 1**: When we want to pass more than one argument to a function and return some value from it.

*ES5 version*:

```
var multiply = function (a, b) {
    return a*b;
};
console.log(multiply(5, 6)); // 30
```

*ES6 version*:

```
var multiplyArrow = (a, b) => a*b;
console.log(multiplyArrow(5, 6)); // 30
```

Note:

The `function` keyword is *not* required.
`=>` is required.
`{}` are optional, when we do not provide `{}` `return` is implicitly added by JavaScript and when we do provide `{}` we need to add `return` if we need it.

**Variant 2**: When we want to pass *only* one argument to a function and return some value from it.

*ES5 version*:

```
var double = function(a) {
    return a*2;
};
console.log(double(2)); // 4
```

*ES6 version*:

```
var doubleArrow  = a => a*2;
console.log(doubleArrow(2)); // 4
```

Note:

When passing only one argument we can omit the parentheses, `()`.

**Variant 3**: When we do *not* want to pass any argument to a function and do *not* want to return any value.

*ES5 version*:

```
var sayHello = function() {
    console.log("Hello");
};
sayHello(); // Hello
```

*ES6 version*:

```
var sayHelloArrow = () => {console.log("sayHelloArrow");}
sayHelloArrow(); // sayHelloArrow
```

**Variant 4**: When we want to explicitly return from arrow functions.

*ES6 version*:

```
var increment = x => {
  return x + 1;
};
console.log(increment(1)); // 2
```

**Variant 5**: When we want to return an object from arrow functions.

*ES6 version*:

```
var returnObject = () => ({a:5});
console.log(returnObject());
```

Note:

We need to wrap the object in parentheses, `()`. Otherwise, JavaScript cannot differentiate between a block and an object.

**Variant 6**: Arrow functions do *not* have `arguments` (an array like object) of their own. They depend upon outer context for `arguments`.

*ES6 version*:

```
function foo() {
  var abc = i => arguments[0];
  console.log(abc(1));
};
foo(2); // 2
```

Note:

`foo` is an ES5 function, with an `arguments` array like object and an argument passed to it is `2` so `arguments[0]` for `foo` is 2.

`abc` is an ES6 arrow function since it does *not* have its own `arguments`. Hence it prints `arguments[0]` of `foo` its outer context instead.

**Variant 7**: Arrow functions do *not* have `this` of their own they depend upon outer context for `this`

*ES5 version*:

```
var obj5 = {
  greet: "Hi, Welcome ",
  greetUser : function(user) {
        setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(this.greet + ": " +  user); // "this" here is undefined.
        });
     }
};

obj5.greetUser("Katty"); //undefined: Katty
```

Note:

The callback passed to setTimeout is an ES5 function and it has its own `this` which is undefined in a `use-strict` environment. Hence we get the output:

```
undefined: Katty
```

*ES6 version*:

```
var obj6 = {
  greet: "Hi, Welcome ",
  greetUser : function(user) {
    setTimeout(() => console.log(this.greet + ": " +  user));
      // This here refers to outer context
   }
};

obj6.greetUser("Katty"); // Hi, Welcome: Katty
```

Note:

The callback passed to `setTimeout` is an ES6 arrow function and it does *not* have its own `this`, so it takes it from its outer context that is `greetUser` which has `this`. That is `obj6` and hence we get the output:

```
Hi, Welcome: Katty
```

**Miscellaneous:**

- We cannot use `new` with arrow functions.
- Arrow functions do *not* have `prototype` property.
- We do *not* have binding of `this` when an arrow function is invoked through `apply` or `call`.

Answer (score 10):

I still stand by everything I wrote in [my first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28135120/1468130) in this thread.  However, my opinion on code style has developed since then, so I have a new answer to this question that builds on my last one.

**Regarding lexical `this`**

In my last answer, I deliberately eschewed an underlying belief I hold about this language, as it was not directly related to the argument I was making.  Nonetheless, without this being explicitly stated, I can understand why many people simply balk at my recommendation to not use arrows, when they find arrows so useful.

My belief is this: we shouldn’t be using `this` in the first place.  Therefore, if a person deliberately avoids using `this` in his code, then the “lexical `this`” feature of arrows is of little to no value.  Also, under the premise that `this` is a bad thing, arrow’s treatment of `this` is less of a “good thing;” instead, it’s more of a form of damage control for another bad language feature.

I figure that this either does not occur to some people, but even to those to whom it does, they must invariably find themselves working within codebases where `this` appears a hundred times per file, and a little (or a lot) of damage control is all a reasonable person could hope for.  So arrows can be good, in a way, when they make a bad situation better.

Even if it is easier to write code with `this` with arrows than without them, the rules for using arrows remain very complex (see: current thread).  Thus, guidelines are neither “clear” nor “consistent,” as you’ve requested.    Even if programmers know about arrows’ ambiguities, I think they shrug and accept them anyway, because the value of lexical `this` overshadows them.

All this is a preface to the following realization: if one does not use `this`, then the ambiguity about `this` that arrows normally cause becomes irrelevant.  Arrows become more neutral in this context.

**Regarding terse syntax**

When I wrote my first answer, I was of the opinion that even slavish adherence to best practices was a worthwhile price to pay if it meant I could produce more perfect code.  But I eventually came to realize that terseness can serve as a form of abstraction that can improve code quality, too — enough so to justify straying from best practices sometimes.

In other words: dammit, I want one-liner functions, too!

**Regarding a guideline**

With the possibility of `this`-neutral arrow functions, and terseness being worth pursuit, I offer the following more lenient guideline:

## Guideline for Function Notation in ES6:

- Don’t use `this`.
- Use function declarations for functions you’d call by name (because they’re hoisted).
- Use arrow functions for callbacks (because they tend to be terser).

Comment: Agree 100% with your "Guideline for Function Notation in ES6" section at the bottom - particularly with hoisting and inline callback functions. nice answer!

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the great answers so far, I'd like to present a very different reason why arrow functions are in a certain sense fundamentally better than "ordinary" JavaScript functions.

For the sake of discussion, let's temporarily assume we use a type checker like [TypeScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript) or Facebook's "Flow". Consider the following toy module, which is valid ECMAScript 6 code plus Flow type annotations (I'll include the untyped code, which would realistically result from Babel, at the end of this answer, so it can actually be run):

```js
export class C {
  n : number;
  f1: number => number;
  f2: number => number;

  constructor(){
    this.n = 42;
    this.f1 = (x:number) => x + this.n;
    this.f2 = function (x:number) { return  x + this.n;};
  }
}
```

Now see what happens when we use the class C from a different module, like this:

```js
let o = { f1: new C().f1, f2: new C().f2, n: "foo" };
let n1: number = o.f1(1); // n1 = 43
console.log(n1 === 43); // true
let n2: number = o.f2(1); // n2 = "1foo"
console.log(n2 === "1foo"); // true, not a string!
```

As you can see, *the type checker failed* here: f2 was supposed to return a number, but it returned a string!

Worse, it seems that *no conceivable type checker* can handle ordinary (non-arrow) JavaScript functions, because the "this" of f2 does not occur in the argument list of f2, so the required type for "this" could not possibly be added as an annotation to f2.

Does this problem also affect people who don't use type checkers? I think so, because even when we have no static types, we think as if they're there. ("The first parameters must be a number, the second one a string" etc.) A hidden "this"-argument which may or may not be used in the function's body makes our mental bookkeeping harder.

Here is the runnable untyped version, which would be produced by Babel:

```js
class C {
    constructor() {
        this.n = 42;
        this.f1 = x => x + this.n;
        this.f2 = function (x) { return x + this.n; };
    }
}

let o = { f1: new C().f1, f2: new C().f2, n: "foo" };
let n1 = o.f1(1); // n1 = 43
console.log(n1 === 43); // true
let n2 = o.f2(1); // n2 = "1foo"
console.log(n2 === "1foo"); // true, not a string!
```

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use arrow functions at all times where access to local `this` is not needed, because arrow functions [do not bind their own *this*, arguments, super, or new.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: Is "super" literal?

Answer (score 3):

Arrow functions or [lambdas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function), were introduced in ES 6. Apart from its elegance in minimal syntax, the most notable functional **difference is scoping of** `this` **inside an arrow function**

> In **regular function** expressions, the `this` keyword is bound to different values based on the *context* in which it is called.
>
> In **arrow functions**, `this` is *lexically* bound, which means it closes over `this` from the scope in which the arrow function was defined (parent-scope), and does not change no matter where and how it is invoked / called.

#### Limitations of arrow functions as methods on an object

```
// this = global Window
let objA = {
  id: 10,
  name: "Simar",
  print () { // same as print: function()
    console.log(`[${this.id} -> ${this.name}]`);
  }
}

objA.print(); // logs: [10 -> Simar]

objA = {
  id: 10,
  name: "Simar",
  print: () => {
    // Closes over this lexically (global Window)
    console.log(`[${this.id} -> ${this.name}]`);
  }
};

objA.print(); // logs: [undefined -> undefined]
```

In the case of `objA.print()` when `print()` method defined using regular `function`, it worked by resolving `this` properly to `objA` for method invocation, but failed when defined as an arrow`=>` function. It is because `this` in a regular function when invoked as a method on an object (`objA`), is the object itself.

However, in case of an arrow function, `this` gets lexically bound to the the `this` of the enclosing scope where it was defined (global / Window in our case) and stays it stays same during its invocation as a method on `objA`.

There are advantages of an arrow-functions over regular functions in method(s) of an object, *but* only when `this` is expected to be fixed and bound at the time of definition.

```
/* this = global | Window (enclosing scope) */

let objB = {
  id: 20,
  name: "Paul",
  print () { // Same as print: function()
    setTimeout( function() {
      // Invoked async, not bound to objB
      console.log(`[${this.id} -> ${this.name}]`);
    }, 1)
  }
};

objB.print(); // Logs: [undefined -> undefined]'

objB = {
  id: 20,
  name: "Paul",
  print () { // Same as print: function()
    setTimeout( () => {
      // Closes over bind to this from objB.print()
      console.log(`[${this.id} -> ${this.name}]`);
    }, 1)
  }
};

objB.print(); // Logs: [20 -> Paul]
```

In the case of `objB.print()` where the `print()` method is defined as function that invokes `console.log(`[${this.id} -> {this.name}]`)` asynchronously as a call-back on `setTimeout` , `this` resolved correctly to `objB` when an arrow function was used as call-back, but failed when the call-back was defined as as regular function.

It is because the arrow `=>` function, passed to `setTimeout(()=>..)`, closed over `this` lexically from its parent, i.e., invocation of `objB.print()` which defined it. In other words, the arrow `=>` function passed in to to `setTimeout(()==>...` bound to `objB` as its `this` because the invocation of `objB.print()` `this` was `objB` itself.

We could easily use `Function.prototype.bind()` to make the call-back defined as a regular function work, by binding it to the correct `this`.

```
const objB = {
  id: 20,
  name: "Singh",
  print () { // The same as print: function()
    setTimeout( (function() {
      console.log(`[${this.id} -> ${this.name}]`);
    }).bind(this), 1)
  }
}

objB.print() // logs: [20 -> Singh]
```

However, arrow functions come in handy and are less error prone for the case of async call-backs where we know the `this` at the time of the functions definition to which it gets and should be bound.

#### Limitation of Arrow-Functions where `this` needs to change across invocations

Anytime, we need a function whose `this` can be changed at the time of invocation, we can’t use arrow functions.

```
/* this = global | Window (enclosing scope) */

function print() {
  console.log(`[${this.id} -> {this.name}]`);
}

const obj1 = {
  id: 10,
  name: "Simar",
  print // The same as print: print
};

obj.print(); // Logs: [10 -> Simar]

const obj2 = {
  id: 20,
  name: "Paul",
};

printObj2 = obj2.bind(obj2);
printObj2(); // Logs: [20 -> Paul]
print.call(obj2); // logs: [20 -> Paul]
```

None of the above will work with arrow function `const print = () => { console.log(`[${this.id} -> {this.name}]`);}` as `this` can’t be changed and will stay bound to the `this` of the enclosing scope where it was defined (global / Window).

In all these examples, we invoked the same function with different objects (`obj1` and `obj2`) one after the another, both of which were created after the `print()` function was declared.

These were contrived examples, but let’s think about some more real life examples. If we had to write our `reduce()` method similar to one that works on `arrays` , we again can’t define it as a lambda, because it needs to infer `this` from the invocation context, i.e., the array on which it was invoked.

For this reason, *constructor* functions can never be defined as arrow functions, as `this` for a constructor function can not be set at the time of its declaration. Every time a constructor function is invoked with the `new` keyword, a new object is created which then gets bound to that particular invocation.

Also when when frameworks or systems accept a callback function(s) to be invoked later with dynamic context `this` , we can’t use arrow functions as again `this` may need to change with every invocation. This situation commonly arises with DOM event handlers.

```
'use strict'
var button = document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function {
  // web-api invokes with this bound to current-target in DOM
  this.classList.toggle('on');
});

var button = document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // TypeError; 'use strict' -> no global this
  this.classList.toggle('on');
});
```

This is also the reason why in frameworks like **Angular 2+** and **Vue.js** expect the template-component binding methods to be regular function / methods as `this` for their invocation is managed by the frameworks for the binding functions. (Angular uses Zone.js to manage an async context for invocations of view-template binding functions.)

On the other hand, in **React**, when we want pass a component's method as an event-handler, for example, `<input onChange={this.handleOnchange} />`, we should define `handleOnchanage = (event)=> {this.props.onInputChange(event.target.value);}` as an arrow function as for every invocation. We want this to be the same instance of the component that produced the JSX for the rendered DOM element.

---

This article is also available in [my Medium](https://medium.com/simars/when-not-to-use-es6-arrow-functions-lambdas-41537a042839?source=friends_link&sk=8fc731e7afa441ee16ec694a499750b9) publication. If you like the article, or have any comments and suggestions, please ***clap*** or leave ***comments*** on [Medium](https://medium.com/simars/when-not-to-use-es6-arrow-functions-lambdas-41537a042839?source=friends_link&sk=8fc731e7afa441ee16ec694a499750b9).

Answer (score 1):

In a simple way,

```
var a = 20; function a() {this.a = 10; console.log(a);}
//20, since the context here is window.
```

Another instance:

```
var a = 20;
function ex(){
    this.a = 10;
    function inner(){
        console.log(this.a); // Can you guess the output of this line?
    }
    inner();
}
var test = new ex();
```

Ans: The console would print 20.

The reason being whenever a function is executed its own stack is created, in this example the `ex` function is executed with the `new` operator so a context will be created, and when `inner` is executed it JavaScript would create a new stack and execute the `inner` function in a `global context` though there is a local context.

So, if we want the `inner` function to have a local context, which is `ex`, then we need to bind the context to the inner function.

Arrows solve this problem. Instead of taking the `Global context`, they take the `local context` if any exist. In the *given example, it will take `new ex()` as `this`.

So, in all cases where binding is explicit, arrows solve the problem by defaults.