# React - Navigate to Redux connected component

Tags: navigation, react-native, redux

I am trying to incorporate Redux into my React native application. I am using the React native Navigator component for app navigation. My renderScene method looks like this (with helper function):

```
var Login = require('./src/ui/views/login/login');
.
.
.
getRoute: function(routeName){

const Routes = {
  Login: Login,
  Waiting: Waiting,
  LogoView: LogoView
};

return Routes[routeName];

},

_renderScene: function(route, navigator) {
 var component = this.getRoute(route.name);
 console.log('Navigate to:');
 console.log(component);
 var props = {
  navigator: navigator
};
 return React.createElement(component, props);
},
```

I export the login component (and the others) like this:

```
module.exports = connect((state) =>{state.token})(Login);
```

It doesn't work to navigate to any view exported with Redux connect wrapper method. The error I get is "`mapStateToProps must return an object. Instead received undefined`". It works fine when exporting the components like this

```
module.exports = Login;
```

Since I want to implement Redux I would be very thankful for any help on exporting with redux "connect()" or any hint on what I am doing wrong

Many thanks!

/Johan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error here in the arrow function inside `connect`. Curly braces don't work here as you expect. If you want to return an object, you should wrap it into parentheses:

```
module.exports = connect((state) => ({token: state.token}))(Login);
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28889451/1297743) for all possible arrow function use-cases.

Also, `{state.token}` is not a valid object literal. You can use shorter form only with identifiers, like this `{state}`.