# Promises not going in order of the "then()"s? (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, promise, response

Why does the then() where it says console.log('THIS COMES BEFORE THE WRITING AND EXTRACTING'); statement come before the writing and extracting to PDFs? I'm new to Promises, so I am a bit confused by this. I want that then() statement to happen AFTER the writing and parsing happens.

```
function writeToPDF(data, fileName) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(fileName), err => {
      reject();
    });
    data.on('end', () => {
      resolve();
    })
  });
}
​
function extractPDF(pdf) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    extract(pdf, {splitPages: false}, (err, text) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        resolve(text);
      }
    });
  });
}
​
request(link).then((success, failure) => {
  let fileName = './name-' + Date.now() + '.pdf';
  writeToPDF(data, fileName).then(() => {
    extractPDF(fileName).then((text) => {
      arrayOfDocuments.push(text);
    })
  }, () => {
    //handle error
  });
}).then(() => {
  console.log('THIS COMES BEFORE THE WRITING AND EXTRACTING');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are nesting your `then` values and actually have two different `then` routes — for lack of a better term.

So far as the javascript is concerned, once the first `then` is resolved in your `request` method, it can move on to the next `then`. Here, once `writeToPdf` is resolved, that part of the promise chain then moves on to the `console.log` statement since the previous promise at that level has been resolved. That make sense?

Comment: How do I get it to do what I want then? I want to writeToPDF and extractPDF and THEN go to the console.log() statement.

Comment: writeToPdf(data, fileName).then(extractPdf).then( // fn for console.log )

Comment: What if I have an array of requests? For example, I have an array of two requests, and one of them is a normal txt file so I wouldn't parse it. I want to run the console.log() statement AFTER both of them are completed. How do I do this?

Comment: Have you looked at Promise.all?  

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 0):

The `request(link).then(...)` block comprises an outer promise chain and two levels of nested promise chain.

If you write a fat-arrow function with a `{block}`, [returns are not explicit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28889451/3478010), therefore :

- neither of the promises derived from `writeToPDF()` or `extractPDF()` is returned,
- the outer promise chain is not informed of the existence of inner promises or their settlement,
- `console.log('THIS COMES BEFORE ...')` relies solely on the fulfillment of the promise returned by `request(link)`, and is guaranteed to occur after PDF stuff commences but before it completes.

```
request(link).then((success, failure) => {
  let fileName = './name-' + Date.now() + '.pdf';
  return writeToPDF(data, fileName).then(() => {
//^^^^^^
    return extractPDF(fileName).then((text) => {
//  ^^^^^^
      arrayOfDocuments.push(text);
    })
  }, () => {
    //handle error
  });
}).then(() => {
  console.log('THIS COMES BEFORE THE WRITING AND EXTRACTING');
});
```