# Define variable and return component from an arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'd like to define a variable inside a `.map()` iteration, as well as returning a component.

But having this variable inside the map doesn't work (gives me error). Is this possible at all, and if so how do I do this?

Below is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

```
render() {
  return(
    <div>
      {array.map( (element, index) => (
        let disturbingVariable = 100 + index
        <MyComponent disturbingVariable={disturbingVariable} />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: What is the error message it gives you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an arrow function has more than one statement you can no longer use the implicit return syntax.

Add block braces and a `return` statement:

```
array.map((element, index) => {
  let disturbingVariable = 100 + index
  return <MyComponent disturbingVariable={disturbingVariable} />
})
```

Alternatively, forgo the variable declaration and perform the addition in-place, maintaining the implicit return:

```
array.map((element, index) =>
  <MyComponent disturbingVariable={100 + index} />)
```

Comment: Right. `x => y` is identical to `function (x) { return y; }`.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could omit return and block braces, but the function body should be one liner with implicit return:

```
render() {
  return(
    <div>
      {array.map((element, index) => <MyComponent disturbingVariable={100 + index}/>)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

More about implicit return [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-return-in-es6-arrow-functions)

Answer (score 2):

here is an example using jsx component

```
const App = () => {
     const firstName = "abey"
     const lastName = "bruck"

     return(
        <p>hello {`${firstName} ${lastName}`}</p> 
     )

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally i use arrows when either

- It's a single instruction function
- I need the `this` remain referencing to the calling context when the arrow is a callback etc...

However the accepted answer states that

> When an arrow function has more than one statement you can no longer
>   use the implicit return syntax.

which is incorrect because we have the comma (`,`) operator and you can still use implicit return. Yet, if you need variable declarations you can not do it with `var`, `let` or `const` keywords while using the comma operator. However you can still declare a variable within the arrow function's scope as an unused argument. Let's see how you may do your code without using braces and explicit return.

```
render() {
  return(
    <div>
      {array.map((e, i, _, disturbingVariable) => (
        disturbingVariable = 100 + i, // comma here
        <MyComponent disturbingVariable={disturbingVariable} />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying to implicitly return value from a function instead of explicitly by using a return statement. If you want to return a value as well as do other operations, you will have to do something like this:-

Notice () converts to {} and use of return statement to explicitly return the component.

```
render() {
  return(
    <div>
      {array.map( (element, index) => {
        let disturbingVariable = 100 + index
        return <MyComponent disturbingVariable={disturbingVariable} />
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: *"you are trying to implicitly return an object (by using ())"* – what ?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't phrase it properly. I meant that OP was implicitly returning a value in an arrow function rather than explicitly via a return statement. () => value is same as () => { return value; }