# React-redux - Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm learning React-Redux and have come to an issue when trying to render out a side navigation "sub section" item from a nested object.

Here is the component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class SideNav extends Component {  
  render() {
    return (
    <div className="sidenav-cont">
        <ul className="top-level-menu">
              {
  this.props.reducerSidenav.map((menuItem) => {
    return (
      <li key={menuItem.catId}>
        <a href="#">{menuItem.parentCat}</a>
        <ul className="bottom-level-menu">
          {  
            this.props.reducerSidenav.subCats.map((subMenuItem) => {
              <li key={subMenuItem.subCatId}><a href="#">{subMenuItem.subCatLabel}</a></li>
            })
          }
        </ul>
      </li>
      )
    })
  }
        </ul>
    </div>
    )
  }
}



function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        reducerSidenav:state.reducerSidenav
    };
} 

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SideNav);
```

if I remove the second nested `<ul>` with the className "bottom-level-menu" then the app renders out my "parent section" list item no problem. But it's when I attempt to re-create the same function but for a nested objected that I get errors. Here is my reducer with the sidenav menu object:

```
export default function(){
    return [
            {
            catId:"parMenu1",
            parentCat:"Bass",
            subCats:[
                {
                    subCatId:"subMenu1",
                    subCatLabel:"base1"
                },
                {
                    subCatId:"subMenu2",
                    subCatLabel:"base2"
                },
                {
                    subCatId:"subMenu3",
                    subCatLabel:"base3"
                },
                {
                    subCatId:"subMenu4",
                    subCatLabel:"base4"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            catId:"parMenu2",
            parentCat:"treb",
            subCats:[
                {
                    subCatId:"subMenu1",
                    subCatLabel:"treb1"
                },
                {
                    subCatId:"subMenu2",
                    subCatLabel:"treb2"
                },
                {
                    subCatId:"subMenu3",
                    subCatLabel:"treb3"
                },
                {
                    subCatId:"subMenu4",
                    subCatLabel:"treb4"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            catId:"parMenu3",
            parentCat:"drums",
            subCats:[
                {
                    subCatId:"subMenu1",
                    subCatLabel:"drums1"
                },
                {
                    subCatId:"subMenu2",
                    subCatLabel:"drums2"
                },
                {
                    subCatId:"subMenu3",
                    subCatLabel:"drums3"
                },
                {
                    subCatId:"subMenu4",
                    subCatLabel:"drums4"
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

As you can see the nested object to be used for the sub navigation items is titled subCats. I would have thought that I could access the object within another object by referring to the sidenav reducer state like so: this.props.reducerSidenav.subCats.map((subMenuItem) => {... much like I did for the parent categories but I'm getting the "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" error in console. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in your code.

```
this.props.reducerSidenav.subCats.map((subMenuItem) => {
                                <li key={subMenuItem.subCatId}><a href="#">{subMenuItem.subCatLabel}</a></li>
                            })
```

reducerSidenav is a table, probably you wanted to have something like this

```
menuItem.subCats.map((subMenuItem) => {
                                <li key={subMenuItem.subCatId}><a href="#">{subMenuItem.subCatLabel}</a></li>
                            })
```

Comment: I tried replacing with menuItem.subCats.map. It doesn't render an error anymore but it's not rendering out any list items. Also I was a little confused in your answer as to where to use this.props.reducerSidenav[index]

Comment: sorry, I wanted to point out how to pick an element from a table by using `this.props.reducerSidenav[index]`, I removed that note from my original answer. Regarding your problem I don't know why there is nothing rendered, maybe add `console.log(menuItem.subCats)` to check what you get from store/state

Comment: Just did and it returns all the objects. I took a screenshot of the console if that helps: https://s18.postimg.org/fa0yqq3c9/Untitled.png

Comment: ok, i know, you dont have a return there `return <li key={subMenuItem.subCatId}><a href="#">{subMenuItem.subCatLabel}</a>`</li>

Comment: That was it, thank you. Just curious do you always have to use return after a .map function?

Comment: you dont need to, there are cases when you dont need to write `return` keyword, here you have more about this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-return-in-es6-arrow-functions

Answer (score 0):

Quote your keys?

```
export default function(){
return [
        {
        "catId":"parMenu1",
        "parentCat":"Bass",
        "subCats":[
            {
                "subCatId":"subMenu1",
                "subCatLabel":"base1"
            },
            {
                "subCatId":"subMenu2",
                "subCatLabel":"base2"
            },
            {
                "subCatId":"subMenu3",
                "subCatLabel":"base3"
            },
            {
                "subCatId":"subMenu4",
                "subCatLabel":"base4"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "catId":"parMenu2",
        "parentCat":"treb",
        "subCats":[
            {
                "subCatId":"subMenu1",
                "subCatLabel":"treb1"
            },
            {
                "subCatId":"subMenu2",
                "subCatLabel":"treb2"
            },
            {
                "subCatId":"subMenu3",
                "subCatLabel":"treb3"
            },
            {
                "subCatId":"subMenu4",
                "subCatLabel":"treb4"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "catId":"parMenu3",
        "parentCat":"drums",
        "subCats":[
            {
                "subCatId":"subMenu1",
                "subCatLabel":"drums1"
            },
            {
                "subCatId":"subMenu2",
                "subCatLabel":"drums2"
            },
            {
                "subCatId":"subMenu3",
                "subCatLabel":"drums3"
            },
            {
                "subCatId":"subMenu4",
                "subCatLabel":"drums4"
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think the "this" keyword inside your first map() function does not reference what you think it does.  You need to bind "this" to the map() function to access the props in the outer object:

```
this.props.reducerSidenav.map((menuItem) => {
    return (
        <li key={menuItem.catId}>
            <a href="#">{menuItem.parentCat}</a>
                <ul className="bottom-level-menu">
                    {  
                        this.props.reducerSidenav.subCats.map((subMenuItem) => {
                            <li key={subMenuItem.subCatId}><a href="#">{subMenuItem.subCatLabel}</a></li>
                        })
                    }
                </ul>
        </li>
        )
    }.bind(this))
 }
```

Comment: Ok, I see you logic but when I bind this to the map function it spits an error saying the . just before bind is an unexptected token

Comment: he doesn't need to bind it because he uses arrow function which automatically binds