# React redux not showing the map content

Tags: reactjs, redux

React Redux not displaying Map content data This code below works by posting form data to database.
My problem is that its not displaying the map content in the return method as per code below and its not showing any error
message in the console. Infact the map content is empty.

```
<ul>
    <h1>Jmarkatti </h1>
    {users.items4 && users.items4.map((user, index) =>
        <option key={user.uid} value='{ user.uid }'>Hey jmarkatti { user.filename} { user.uid }</option>
        )}
</ul>
```

Some Post here at **Stackoverflow** suggest ensuring that all the one doe not miss the returning statement
[list.map not being displayed in React Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42307836/list-map-not-being-displayed-in-react-component)

here is the main code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { uActions } from '../_actions';

class FileRegister extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            user: {
                firstName: '',
            },
            submitted: false
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        const { user } = this.state;
        this.setState({
            user: {
                ...user,
                [name]: value,
            },
        });
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ submitted: true });
        const { user_upload } = this.state;
        const { dispatch } = this.props;
        if (user.firstName) {
            dispatch(userActions.register_upload(user));
        }
    }
    render() {
        const { user, users } = this.props;
        const { registering } = this.props;
        const { user, submitted } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <ul>
                    <h1>Jmarkatti </h1>
                        {users.items4 && users.items4.map((user, index) =>
                        <option key={user.uid} value='{ user.uid }' >Hey jmarkatti {user.filename} {user.uid}</option>
                    )}
                </ul>
                <h2>Form submission</h2>
                <form name="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <div className={'form-group' + (submitted && !user.firstName ? ' has-error' : '')}>
                        <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="firstName" value={user.firstName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        {submitted && !user.firstName &&
                            <div className="help-block">First Name is required</div>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <button className="btn btn-primary">Register</button>

                        <Link to="/login" className="btn btn-link">Cancel</Link>
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Updates**

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { registering } = state.users;

 const { users} = state;
 const { user} = state;




    return {
        registering,
user,
users


    };
}

const connectedFileRegister = connect(mapStateToProps)(FileRegister);
export { connectedFileRegister as FileRegister };
```

Here is the **reducer.js**

```
import { uConstants } from '../_constants';
export function users(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case userConstants.REGISTER_REQUEST:
            return { registering: true };
        case userConstants.REGISTER_SUCCESS:
            return { items4: action.users };
        //return{};
        case userConstants.REGISTER_FAILURE:
            return {};
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: it would seem that `users.items4` evaluates to `false`

Comment: can you add code as well where you are connecting your component with redux connect ?

Comment: @Pranay, I have added the connecting components. Please can you look into it in the update sections

Comment: Why do you do `const { users} = state;
 const { user} = state;`. Just do: `const { users, user } = state`;

Comment: @Frankez I have done that yet Map content is not showed. and there is no error message in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resloved in the dispatch() method as there was a mistake. Instead of **userAction.users()**, I wrote **userAction.register_upload()**. 
In a nutshell, it should be

```
dispatch(userActions.users(user));
```

not

```
 dispatch(userActions.register_upload(user));
```

If you look at second line of code at **reducer.js** posted above, you will discover export functions was set to **users** as per the code below

```
export function users(state = {}, action) {
```

Map content is working now. Between Thanks everyone

Answer (score -1):

The way you iterate `users.items4` will not return `<option>` items as you expected. Change them to

```
{users.items4 && users.items4.map((user, index) => (
  <option key={user.uid} value={user.uid} >Hey jmarkatti {user.filename} {user.uid}</option>
))}
```

or

```
{users.items4 && users.items4.map((user, index) => {
  return <option key={user.uid} value={user.uid} >Hey jmarkatti {user.filename} {user.uid}</option>
})}
```

Comment: Yes it does. If you don't include curly brackets at the start of an arrow function, anything encapsulated is returned.

Comment: You are right @FrankerZ. Should've tested before posting.