# react component with arrow function weird behavior

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am following the official redux tutorial with this code (it works!)

```
const TodoList = ( {todos} ) => (
    <ul>
        { todos.map( todo => 
            <li key={todo.id}>{todo.name}</li>
        )}
    </ul>
)
```

I have been playing around with the syntax and this also works:

```
const TodoList = ( {todos} ) => (
    <ul>
        { todos.map( todo => {
            return <li key={todo.id}>{todo.name}</li>
        })}
    </ul>
)
```

but this does not work:

```
const TodoList = ( {todos} ) => (
    <ul>
        { todos.map( todo => {
            <li key={todo.id}>{todo.name}</li>
        })}
    </ul>
)
```

Can anyone explain the difference between them and why the third one fails?

Comment: It's because the third example is not returning anything. The syntax `(args) => { statements }` creates a block to house statements. The syntax `(args) => expression` implicitly returns `expression`, but not in the first syntax. The first syntax uses a block and does not implicitly return a value and thus returns undefined unless you give it a return statement. Read the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the arrow function

```
todo => {
    <li key={todo.id}>{todo.name}</li>
}
```

returns nothing and you will get an array that contains `undefined`s ( based on the length of `todos`). For example:

```
const ary = [1, 2, 3].map(el => { console.log(el) })
console.log(ary) // [undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

You must return something in the callback of `.map()`

If the callback only contains 1 expression and returns immediately, you can omit the `{ }` and `return`.

```
const foo = () => {
  return 'foo'
}
```

is equal to

```
const foo = () => 'foo'
```

So now you can:

```
const TodoList = ( {todos} ) => (
    <ul>
        { todos.map( todo => (
            <li key={todo.id}>{todo.name}</li>
        ))}
    </ul>
)
```

also the `( )` is not a must, you can omit that if you preferred:

```
const TodoList = ( {todos} ) => (
    <ul>
      { todos.map(todo => <li key={todo.id}>{todo.name}</li>) }
    </ul>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference has to do with how you specify the body of the arrow function.

```
{ todos.map( todo => 
    <li key={todo.id}>{todo.name}</li>
)}
```

Is an expression within the body and by default does not need a return statement,

```
  <ul>
    { todos.map(todo => <li key={todo.id}>{todo.name}</li>) }
  </ul>
```

When defined within a block, a return statement needs to be included .

Comment: Ya meant to type when returning within a block. Adjusted answer

Answer (score 0):

Here, You nicely added a block statement , In block statement implicit return is syntactically ambiguous, now it returns undefined. In ES6 arrow function return is implicit under some circumstances. Like You added a block it made undefined. You can find more detail in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-return-in-es6-arrow-functions) post.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation for [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control), you have to **return** a value, which will be the new value in the new array created by the map function. This means that `return` has to exist in the callback of your map function, whether stated explicitly or implicitly.

The arrow functions you have declared as a callback (e.g `todo => <li key={todo.id}>{todo.name}</li>`) in the first and the second example are equal. You may want to refer to different ways to declare arrow functions in the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

In the third example however, you are returning a [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) of code without a return statement. The default behavior of the javascript runtime is to return undefined. Here are some code to demonstrate this behavior:

```js
const test = () => { var a; /* a block of code with no return statement */ }

const a = test();

console.log(a);
```

Hence, the elements of the array that is returned from the map function in your third example will undefined. This is the main reason why your todos are not getting rendered in your list.