# Want to pass data to other component - ListView

Tags: ios, listview, react-native, react-native-ios

I have added and imported the `sample data`. I want to list out data from this file in a `list view` and I'm passing the data to the Row Component for `RenderRow`. But getting error saying

> Row(...): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, View, ListView, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Row from './app/Row';
import data from './app/Data';

export default class ListViewDemo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  const rowHasChanged = (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
  const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged});
  this.state = {
    dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(data),
  };
  render() {
   return (
     <ListView
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={(data) => <Row {...data} />} // Getting error here
     />
   );
  }
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent('DemoApp',() => ListViewDemo)
```

These my sample **Data.js** You can check the [data here](https://gist.github.com/spencercarli/d79bd0a017212fcfee5f5133148ce162).

```
export default data = [
   {...}, {...}
];
```

**Row.js:**

```
const Row = (props) => {
 <View Style={styles.container}>
  <Image source={{ uri: props.picture.large}} />
  <Text >
   {`${props.name.first} ${props.name.last}`}
  </Text>
 </View>
}
```

What would be the problem?

Comment: You need to post what your `Row` component looks like and examples of what your actual `data` looks like. Otherwise, it could be anything.

Comment: @MichaelCheng updated. Plz check now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ES6 only returns when there is no explicit blocks:

```
const cb = (param) => param * 2;
```

You should explicitly return:

```
const Row = (props) => {
    return (
        <View Style={styles.container}>
            <Image source={{ uri: props.picture.large}} />
            <Text >
                {`${props.name.first} ${props.name.last}`}
            </Text>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-return-in-es6-arrow-functions) for further explanation.

Comment: Thanx mate. Its worked! And thanks for the resource too.

Answer (score 0):

Change this Line  to

```
renderRow={(data) => <Row {...data} />}
```

To This

```
 renderRow={(data) =><Row {...this.props} />}
```

This may help you to get props in the row Component