# forEach sum with arrow function gives unexpected results in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

From Firebase Cloud Functions I do query in Firebase Realtime DB like this:

```
let logs = this.firebase.database()
.ref('logs')
.orderByChild("userId").equalTo(userId)
.once('value');
```

Returned data:

```
{
  "id1abc": {
    "myValue": 1,
    "userId": "abc"
  },
  "id2abc": {
    "myValue": 2,
    "userId": "abc"
  },
  "id3abc": {
    "myValue": 3,
    "userId": "abc"
  }
}
```

Query returns a couple entries which values which I would like to sum:

```
let loggedVal = 0;
logs.forEach(log => {
    loggedVal += log.val().myValue;
});
return loggedVal;
```

Arrow function inside forEach gives me proper value in this case (Sum equals 6).

But when I remove parenthesis like here:

```
let loggedVal = 0;
logs.forEach(log => loggedVal += log.val().myValue);
return loggedVal;
```

Returned value isn't sum, but just value from the first element which I'm iterating over (loggedVal == 6). Can anyone explain where does the difference come from?

Comment: How can you use `forEach` in an `Object` in the first place? The returned data you showed to us is not an `Array` eligible to `Array.forEach`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the firbase [forEach](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#forEach) docs,

> You can cancel the enumeration at any point by having your forEach callback
>   function return true.

Here in your second case,

```
logs.forEach(log => loggedVal += log.val().myValue);
```

You are returning some value in your first iteration (because [you are not using parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-return-in-es6-arrow-functions/28889451#28889451)), which is considered true. Therefore it stops further iteration, hence you do not get sum but first value.

Comment: I knew that it will be something in javascript basics! Just couldn't find a proper question to ask. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you misunderstand about the arrow function format.

the 1st one:

```
let loggedVal = 0;
logs.forEach(log => {
  loggedVal += log.val().myValue;
 });
 return loggedVal;
```

it's equal to ES5:

```
let loggedVal = 0;
logs.forEach(function(log){
  loggedVal += log.val().myValue;
 });

 return loggedVal;
```

but the 2nd one:

```
 let loggedVal = 0;
 logs.forEach(log => loggedVal += log.val().myValue);
 return loggedVal;
```

it's equal to in ES5:

```
 let loggedVal = 0;
 logs.forEach(function(log){
    return loggedVal += log.val().myValue);
 }); 
 return loggedVal;
```

arrow function `=> abc()` mean `{ return abc()}`, but `=> { abc }` it means `{abc(); return;}`.

an as the document of firebase :

> You can cancel the enumeration at any point by having your forEach callback function return true.

at the first item: `return loggedVal += log.val().myValue); // === true`, so that it stopped your recursive `.forEach`.

p.s: Someone also misunderstand `=> { abc }` equals to `{ return { abc :abc} }`

Answer (score 0):

Here it's what it should look like

```
const logs = {
  id1abc: {
    myValue: 1,
    userId: 'abc',
  },
  id2abc: {
    myValue: 2,
    userId: 'abc',
  },
  id3abc: {
    myValue: 3,
    userId: 'abc',
  },
};

Object.keys(logs).reduce((tmp, x) => tmp + logs[x].myValue, 0);
```