# the difference between "map((respone) => respone.json())" and "map((respone) =>{ respone.json();})"

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

here is the source code:

```
export class PostComponent implements OnInit {

    posts: any[];

    constructor(private http: Http, private service: PostService) {
    }
    getAll1() {
    const url = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
    this.http.get(url)
    .map((respone) => respone.json())
    .subscribe(posts => this.posts = posts );
    }  
  }
```

`

it works fine,but if I add curly braces for "respone.json",  then visual stdio code hint a error(see below).
after add the curly braces the source code like below:

```
export class PostComponent implements OnInit {

    posts: any[];

    constructor(private http: Http, private service: PostService) {
    }
    getAll1() {
    const url = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
    this.http.get(url)
    .map((respone) => {respone.json();})
    .subscribe(posts => this.posts = posts );
    }  
  }
```

the error is on word "this.posts" of the last line,the erroris :[ts] Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.

why?

Comment: `{response.json();}` doesn't return a value

Comment: You appear to be using Typescript, adding this as a tag might get more hits.

Comment: See also [When should I use `return` in es6 Arrow Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28889450/218196)

Answer (score 4):

`.map((respone) => respone.json())` is actually the same as this:

```
.map((respone) => { return respone.json() })
```

While `.map((respone) => { respone.json() })` is similar to this:

```
.map((respone) => { respone.json(); return undefined; })
```

Therefore, in your second code block, the `respone.json()` is just dismissed.

Comment: thank all,I understand.