# Javascript map over two dimensional array

Tags: javascript

I have this array:

```
rows = [ [ 89, 18, 9 ], [ 1903, 3, 4 ], [ 3, 1, 800 ] ];
```

It should look like this:

```
[ [ 89, 1903, 3 ], [ 18, 3, 1 ], [ 9, 4, 800 ] ]
```

And the code, that is working, looks like this:

```
rows[0].map((_, columnIndex) => rows.map(
            row => row[columnIndex])
        );
```

How does this work?

Comment: The description for the 2d tag is `2D computer graphics is the computer-based generation of digital images—mostly from two-dimensional models.` - totally not what you're talking about

Comment: You're _transposing_ your data structure, which only works with that code because it's *square*. Either way, perhaps you could explain which parts confuse you? Did you check up on what `map` does yet?

Comment: I understand what map does, but i don't understand how the second chained map gets to the right array elements. Can you explain me that?

Comment: @Jeroen Doesn't have to be square. It could be any rectangular array. It's just that the names of the variables are misleading. I'd rather write `rows[0].map((_, columnIndex) => rows.map(row => row[columnIndex]))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
                  +--- The outter function map gets the first array to loop through the rows
[ 89,   18, 9   ] |
[ 1903, 3,  4   ] |
[ 3,    1,  800 ] v
  +--->
  |
  +- The nested function map is looping through the columns.
     The key here is the fixed column using index (column[index])
     from the outter function map, so every iteration from the outter
     function map will fix the access to that column, i.e -
     index = 0 will access the array as follow: array[j][0], array[j+1, 0], ... array[n, 0]
                                                         ^              ^                ^
```

This is an approach to illustrate what's happening using direct index accesses.

```js
var rows = [ [ 89, 18, 9 ], [ 1903, 3, 4 ], [ 3, 1, 800 ] ];

var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < rows[0].length; i++) {
  result[i] = new Array(rows[0].length).fill();

  for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
    result[i][j] = rows[j][i]; // Here is the fixed column access using the outter index i.
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Was just writing my own near identical answer. +1. My for loop was slightly different to yours though: `for(var i = 0; i < rows[0].length; i++){
  result.push([]);
  for(var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++){
    result[result.length-1].push(rows[j][i]);
  }
}`

Comment: @Zze yes, it was similar!

Answer (score 8):

I'll assume you are simply not accustomed to the particular language features being used here, hence why you can't follow what is going on, so here goes:

- Your structure is a nested `Array`. Hence the nested `Array.map`s.
- Both `map` callbacks make use of [implicit return](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41602806/1814486).

which unfolds to this:

```
rows[0].map((row, index) => {
  return rows.map((column) => {
    return column[index]
  })
})
```

The 2 arguments passed to the `map` callback are the following:

- `element`: The currently iterated Array element; In your first `map` this is the `row` argument.
- `i`: The current iteration number, starting from 0; In your first `map` this is the `index` argument.

That's all there is to it. From then on you just follow the iterations and the values of each argument at each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Iterator Methods (like `map`,`forEach`,`filter`...) dealing with array 2d as every element is 1d array

For example:

```
    arr= [[1,0,0],
          [0,1,0],
          [0,0,1]]
    arr.map( (item)=> {
           item.forEach( (element)=> {
             //...
            //...
           })
    })
```

The first iterator (`map`) take the first row in arr array in this example `[1,0,0]`

The second iterator takes the second row of arr that is `[0,1,0]`  **save it in item** and so on...

In a nested loop (`foreach`) that take the real number like `0` or `1`. Here the code can deal with it.

Comment: This answer is a bit unclear for me. _Save it in item? Here the code can deal with it?_ What does this mean?