# How do I get to a nested array in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to get to the nested array and more specifically to the "dishes" array through the map () method, but to no avail.

```js
const RESTAURANTS = [
    {
        id: "1",
        name: "Filada Family bar",
        type: "Bakery",
        rating: "5.0",
        favorite: true,
        hotOffer: true,
        hotOfferPromo: require("../images/offers/offer_1.png"),
        dishes: [
            {
                id: "1",
                name: "Filada Family bar",
                category: "cake",
                type: "Asian food",
                rating: "5.0",
                distance: "0.2 km - $$ -",
                image: require("../images/restaurants/restaurant_1.jpg"),
            },
        ],
    },
];
```

I usually only use the following code for the first array, but I need the data from the "dishes" array.

```js
{RESTAURANTS.map((item) => (
  <View key={item.id}>
      <Text>{item.name}</Text>
  </View>
))}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript map over two dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49120825/javascript-map-over-two-dimensional-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is just plain javascript. You can either loop restaurants and get dishes or access a restaurant by the index in the array and get the result (or maybe search, filter whatever you need.)

access and index and the dishes property on the object:

```js
{RESTAURANTS[0].dishes.map((item) => (
    <View key={item.id}>
        <Text>{item.name}</Text>
    </View>
))}
```

Looping restaurants:

```js
{RESTAURANTS.map((restaurant) => {
   return restaurant.dishes.map((dish) => (
      <View key={dish.id}>
          <Text>{dish.name}</Text>
      </View>
   ))
})}
```

What you need to understand here is that you have an array of objects. When mapping, the `item` variable means one of these objects that are being looped through and you can access any property like you would in a regular object.