# Promise.all() and catching errors

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch, es6-promise

I wrote a snippet of code that gets some a JSON from the Foursquare API. From this JSON, I get IDs of venues. These IDs are then used to get more details from those specific venues by issuing a `fetch()` request for every ID, and mapping those requests in an array. That array is then passed into `Promise.all()`. When the API is available, everything works, but it's the error catching that I can't get my head around.

```
fetch(`https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?${params}`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
      const venueIds = data.response.venues.map(venue => venue.id)

      const venuePromises = venueIds.map(venueId => {
        fetch(`https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/${venueId}?${otherParams}`)
          .then(response => {
            // Must check for response.ok, because 
            // catch() does not catch 429
            if (response.ok) {
              console.log('ok')
              return response.json()
            } else {
              Promise.reject('Error when getting venue details')
            }
          })
      })

      Promise.all(venuePromises).then(data => {
        const venues = data.map(entry => entry.response.venue)  // Error for this line
        this.parseFsqData(venues)
      }).catch((e) => {console.log(e); getBackupData()})
  }).catch((e) => {console.log(e); getBackupData()})

  function getBackupData() {
    console.log('backup')
  }
```

When the API is not available, I get the following console errors (and more of the same):

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'response' of undefined
    at MapsApp.js:97
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at MapsApp.js:97

backup

api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4b7efa2ef964a520c90d30e3?client_id=ANDGBLDVCRISN1JNRWNLLTDNGTBNB2I4SZT4ZQYKPTY3PDNP&client_secret=QNVYZRG0JYJR3G45SP3RTOTQK0SLQSNTDCYXOBWUUYCGKPJX&v=20180323:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 429 ()

Uncaught (in promise) Error when getting venue details
```

I don't understand why `then()` after Promise.all() is entered, because `response` is never `ok` (there is no `ok` logged in console). Also, I don't understand why the `console.log()`'s in the `catch()` blocks aren't executed, or why they are empty. I don't see any caught error information in console, but still the `getBackupData` function is called. Finally, it is unclear why the last message in console indicates that the error is *uncaught*, as I expected `reject()` to make `Promise.all()` fail.

How can I tactfully catch any errors (included those not normally caught by `catch()`, such as 429 errors) and call `getBackupData` when any errors occur?

Comment: You don't return that `Promise.reject('Error when getting venue details')`, so that index of `venuePromises` has the value `undefined`, rather than a rejected Promise.

Comment: @tehhowch nice answer you got there..... as a comment.

Comment: @escapesequence feels like a "caused by typo" question. I don't answer those. Now that I look at more of the code though, there's more missed `return` statements so it's time to write one

Comment: @tehhowch fair enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issues are related: namely, the Promise chain must be `return`ed. If you do not `return` the Promise, you disconnect any of the caller's `Promise#catch` handling, and any errors in your Promise / `then` code will result in unhandled promise rejection errors, such as what you have obtained:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error when getting venue details

This uncaught promise rejection appears in your code that handles the resolution of `fetch`:

```
if (response.ok) {
  console.log('ok')
  return response.json()
} else {
  Promise.reject('Error when getting venue details')  // <----
}
```

Since this code is being used to construct your `venuePromises` array, its `return` value will populate `venuePromises`. If the response was ok, that array element will have the response JSON from `return response.json()`. If the response failed, there is no `return` statement that executes, so the array element has the value `undefined`. Thus, `venuePromises` would look like this:

```
[
  { /** some object for successful response */ },
  undefined,
  { /** some other object */ },
  ...
]
```

Thus when this array is accessed by your `Promise.all`'s success handler, you get the TypeError since you expected all elements of `venuePromises` to be valid. This TypeError is caught by the `Promise.all`'s `.catch` handler (which is why it is logged, and you receive the "backup" text in your log).

To fix, you need to `return` the `Promise.reject`, *and also* the `Promise.all`. Note that there are some cases of [implicit `return`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-return-in-es6-arrow-functions), but I find it nicer to be explicit, especially if the statement spans multiple lines. Since you're returning the `Promise.all` statement, you can offload its `.then` and `.catch` to the caller, resulting in one less nesting level, and one fewer duplicated `.catch` handler.

```
fetch(`https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?${params}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(jsonData => {
        const venueIds = jsonData.response.venues.map(venue => venue.id);
        const venuePromises = venueIds.map(venueId => {
            let link = `https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/${venueId}?${otherParams}`;
            return fetch(link).then(response => {
                // Must check for response.ok, because catch() does not catch 429
                if (response.ok) {
                    console.log('ok');
                    return response.json();
                } else {
                    console.log(`FAILED: ${link}`);
                    // Return a Promise
                    return Promise.reject(`Error when getting venue details for '${venueId}'`);
                }
            });
        });

        return Promise.all(venuePromises);
    })
    .then(venueData => {
        const venues = venueData.map(entry => entry.response.venue);
        this.parseFsqData(venues);
    })
    .catch(e => {console.log(e); getBackupData()});

function getBackupData() {
    console.log('backup')
}
```

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. I appreciate the thorough explanation. After applying your fixes, the code does indeed run as expected. *I think.* The API returns a 429 error for now (which I don't mind), and my code falls back on backup data. However, Chrome's console still shows all failed GET requests (error 429). Does that mean that I am still missing some errors that I didn't catch, or is this some browser behaviour that you can't get around when encountering failed GET requests?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Chrome's console, so I can't help you there. You should probably also be passing the venue data or the backup data to `this.parseFsqData` (or something), i.e. `.then(venueData => venueData.map(entry => entry.response.venue)).catch(e => { console.log(e); return getBackupData()}).then(venues => { this.parseFsqData(venues); });`

Answer (score 1):

Try returning the rejected promise.

```
return Promise.reject('Error when getting venue details')
```

Comment: In addition to your answer, the inner `fetch()` should also be returned to the `map()` function. Cf. tehhowch's and Martín Zaragoza's answers for additional fixes.

Answer (score 1):

When working with promises you should return inner promises instad of working with inner "thens".

Check this:

```
fetch(`https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?${params}`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
      const venueIds = data.response.venues.map(venue => venue.id);

      const venuePromises = venueIds.map(venueId => {
        fetch(`https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/${venueId}?${otherParams}`)
          .then(response => {
            // Must check for response.ok, because 
            // catch() does not catch 429
            if (response.ok) {
              console.log('ok')
              return response.json()
            } else {
              return Promise.reject('Error when getting venue details')
            }
          })
      });

      return Promise.all(venuePromises)
  })
  .then(venueValues => {
    const venues = venueValues.map(entry => entry.response.venue);  // Error for this line
    this.parseFsqData(venues);
  })
  .catch((e) => {console.log(e); getBackupData()})


function getBackupData() {
    console.log('backup')
}
```

When returning Promise.all as a value, you're returning a promise so that you can chain further "then" callbacks. The last catch shall capture all promise rejects.

You're also missing the return in the else clause

Hope this helps

Comment: In addition to your answer, the inner `fetch()` should also be returned to the `map()` function. Cf. tehhowch's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the solution is fairly simple; The response of the nested fetch method is missing a return statement. You should get rid of that mysterious error once it is in place.

```
const venuePromises = venueIds.map(venueId => {
    <missing return statement here> fetch(`https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/${venueId}?${otherParams}`)
      .then(response => {
```