# Shorthand method definition

Tags: javascript, object, methods

I'm running this code:

```
const myobj ={
mynum: ()=>{console.log("1")},
}
console.log(myobj.mynum())
```

It returns: 
1
undefined

Where is "undefined" comes from? What's the main purpose to create a method like that? Is it even a method?

Comment: you're not returning anything.  See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-return-in-es6-arrow-functions

Comment: No, [an arrow function is never a "method"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/1048572). "*Shorthand method definition*" does refer to [this syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions).

Answer (score 2):

The undefined comes from the fact that the function doesn't return anything. Take for example

```
() => 3
```

That function will return a 3, notice that there isn't any `{}` around the function, and thus the last value evaluated will be returned.

Then take for instance this function:

`() => { return 3; }`

That will also return a 3 because we have explicitly added a return statement.

In your case you would need to add an explicit return statement if you want to use the `{}` braces, however `console.log` also returns undefined, so in your case either way would produce `undefined` as a result.

Comment: @RyanB true but that isn't necessarily part of the method declaration, rather it gets evaluated as a math expression, so the function still has the form `()=>3` for example `()=>(5-2)`