# Is the creation of a Promise synchronous?

Tags: javascript, promise

I need to write a function which makes two chained HTTP calls and act upon the result once the results of the second call are available.

The approach I thought would works is

```js
function getdata() {
  return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(r => fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2`)
      .then(s => s.json())
    )
}
let m = getdata()
m.then(x => console.log(JSON.stringify(x)))
```

This works fine, the console output is as expected.

I then ported the idea to my actual call, the main difference being that the HTTPS calls are slow. For the sake of mapping the actual error to code, consider a small variation of the code above (with some logging added)

```js
function getdata() {
  return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(r => fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2`)
      .then(s => {
        console.log(s)
        s.json()
      })
    )
}
let m = getdata()
m.then(x => console.log(x))
```

The console output (from my actual code) is similar to

```
11:36:56.388 undefined
11:36:56.456 filter-sentinels.js:42 Response {type: "cors", url: …}
```

In details:

- the first `undefined` is from `console.log(x)`
- the second line is from  `console.log(s)`

It would seem that the Promise is resolved in the second line, which comes after the first one. This is normal, it is what promises are for.

What I do not understand is **why the `.then()` in `m.then(x => console.log(x) ))` is executed when the promise is not resolved yet?**

A note on the title: what I actually want to understand is whether I can treat a Promise being generated (`let m = ...`) as something synchronous - in the sense that I can safely apply a `then()` to it and what happens in the `then()` will happen when relevant information is known (the HTTP call has returned).

Comment: Change `s.json()` to `return s.json()`

Comment: each `.then` is returning a promise, except the last one, where `s.json` is not returned. In general, anyway, the code inside the promise callback is called **after** the promise is resolved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that there is one Promise in the neseted `fetch` which is not being chained with the outer ones, the `s.json()`:

```
.then(s => {
  console.log(s)
  s.json() // <---- This is not being returned; the Promise chain will resolve to undefined
})
```

You're just *declaring* the `s.json()` Promise, but you're not returning it, or using it at all, so the entire `getdata()` Promise resolves to `undefined`, once the response from `/totos/2` comes back.

Return the final nested `.json()` call, and it works as expected:

```js
function getdata() {
  return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(r => fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2`)
      .then(s => {
        console.log(s)
        return s.json()
      })
    )
}
m = getdata()
m.then(x => console.log(x) )
```

Comment: Thank you. In that case, why does the first code work as expected?

Comment: Because the inner `.json` is being (implicitly) returned by the arrow function. (Arrow functions with blocks `{` `}` like in the second code do not ever implicitly return anything, so you need the `return` statement)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-return-in-es6-arrow-functions

Comment: I understand, thanks. I also see that I would be better off (at least from a personal readability perspective) chaining flat `then()` calls.