# Page.evaluate() returns undefined, but statement works in Chrome devTools

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to get the `src` values for all images on Bing image search for a search term. I am using puppeteer for it. I wrote a selector to grab each image tag and it works in the Chrome DevTools. It, however, isn't working when I write it in the code-

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
    try{
        let url = `https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=cannabis`
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false})
        const page = await browser.newPage()
        await page.goto(url)
        await page.waitForSelector("ul.dgControl_list li img.mimg")

        console.log(await page.evaluate(() => {
            Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("ul.dgControl_list>li img.mimg"), img => img.src)
        }))
    } catch(err){
        console.log("error - " + err)
    }
})()
```

I get the output as an object containing arrays of 10 items each in the devTools, but when I run it in the console through my code, it is undefined. How do I read this object?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use a return statement in ES6 arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-a-return-statement-in-es6-arrow-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning any data from the `page.evaluate` call. To return the data you have to use the `return` statement or use the short syntax (as explained below):

```js
console.log(await page.evaluate(() => {
    return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("ul.dgControl_list>li img.mimg"), img => img.src)
}))
```

#### Explanation: Arrow function

The arrow function has two ways to write them. One is the short syntax, you can use it like this:

```js
const func = () => 1; // func() will simply return 1
```

You can only put in one statement in there (which might call other statements though). Alternatively, you can use the long form:

```js
const func = () => { return 1; }; // Same function as above
```

You can use variable declarations and any kind of code inside this function (just as in a normal `function() { ... }`, but this time you have to use `return` to return a value.

Therefore, as an alternative, you could also write this (short syntax):

```js
console.log(await page.evaluate(
    () => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("ul.dgControl_list>li img.mimg"), img => img.src)
))
```

Comment: Thanks buddy! I realized I was using the short syntax but threw the curly braces in there. :)