# Cannot figure out how to wait for Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I have an array with user IDs and I need to find out what name belongs to each ID and return them in an array.
I can get the user's name from the database, using knex and push them into an array, but when I try to send the data it is always an empty array.

I am not really good with Promises so can't figure out how to apply to my project.

```
const userId = [10,11,12,13]
let users = []

userId.map(id => {
    db.select('name').from('users').where('user_id', id)
    .then(user => {
        users.push(user)
    })
})
res.json(users)
```

I want the response to wait until the looping finishes and send the users array.

Comment: i can help u with the ans but trust me start reading about await/async, Promises try this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise  a good dev always reads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `map` is creating an array of `undefined` because your callback function doesn't return anything. If we tweak it slightly, it'll create an array of promises, which conveniently is exactly what [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) expects. :-) So:

```
const userId = [10,11,12,13]
Promise.all(
    userId.map(id => db.select('name').from('users').where('user_id', id))
)
.then(users => {    // `users` is an array of users, in the same order as the IDs
    res.json(users);
})
.catch(error => {
    // Render an error response
});
```

Comment: [worth mentioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-return-in-es6-arrow-functions)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to wait for all promises to finish before running `res.json(...)`

Second, you shouldn't mutate outside variables after promise resolving (the order by which the promises resolve will alter your output and that is not nice.

Something like this should work fine

```js
const userId = [10,11,12,13]

// map userId array to promise array
// Promise.all aggregates a promise array into one big promise that resolves when all promises resolve (and preserves array order)
Promise.all(
  userId.map(id =>
    db
      .select("name")
      .from("users")
      .where("user_id", id)
  )
)
  .then(users => res.json(users))
  .catch(e => console.error("Error::", e));

/*handle error in the catch block*/

/* visual example of Promise.all.then block
Promise.all([           users = [
   getUser(10),    ->     {userId: 10, ....}
   getUser(11),    ->     {userId: 11, ....}
   getUser(12)     ->     {userId: 12, ....}
])                      ]

*/
```

Comment: That `return` is useless and might be confusing to the OP

Comment: @JonasWilms depending on the environment some require to `return` the Promise so it doesn't hang the request (e.g. firebase functions) but you are right, habits.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative answer, here's how you could make 1 trip to the DB for this particular query meaning you don't need to wait for multiple Promises and reduce the load on your DB

```
knex.raw(
  'select name from users where user_id in (' + userId.map(_ => '?').join(',') + ')', 
  [...userId]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `Promise.all()`, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Try

```
const userId = [10,11,12,13]

let users = userId.map(id => new Promise(resolve => {
    db.select('name').from('users').where('user_id', id)
    .then(user => {
        resolve(user)
    })
}))
Promise.all(users).then(()=>res.json(users))
```

Here `users` is an array of promises. As soon as all of them are resolved, do `res.json(users)`.