# Write a function using some method that checks if an item in the array is equal to null (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I can't seem to get this test to pass:

```
hasNull([1, null, 3])
```

Expected: `true` but got: `false`

My function:

```
function hasNull(arr) {
  return arr.some((item)=>{ item === null }) ? true : false
}
```

Comment: You're not returning from the arrow function. Change it to `arr.some((item)=> item === null )`. You don't need the ternary, since `Array.some()` returns a boolean anyway.

Comment: The ternary is useless, it already returns a Boolean.

Comment: When you specify {}, you must use `return`. Just remove {} and your solution should work.

Comment: You're doing `true ? true : false` or `false ? true : false`. The ternary is redundant.

Comment: Relevant dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-return-in-es6-arrow-functions

Answer (score 4):

I made it a bit shorter then your solution. If you remove the curly brackets `{}` from the array function then it will return the value of `item === null` check other than that it is just `undefined` that's why it does not pass any value for `some()` from your array.

Plus one suggestion is ternary operator in this case is useless because [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) returns a `boolean` already, see the documentation:

> The some() method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

I guess this can work for you with the following one liner:

```js
const hasNull = arr => arr.some(item => item === null);

console.log(hasNull([1, null, 3]));
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: `const has = value => arr => arr.some(item => item === value);
const hasNull = has(null);` if they want to create other kinds of checks as well :)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing return statement:

```
function hasNull(arr) {
  return arr.some((item) => { return item === null })
}
```