# => pointing to {} causes a TypeError:Undefined when calling the class method and chaining a .then to the inner function's returned <Promise>. Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, arrow-functions

- I have a class that uses class methods to call an API. The calls to
  the API return a Promise object.
- When I call the class method on an
  instance of the class, and use .then, **if my arrow function in the
  class method declaration points to a { }, I get a TypeError:
  Undefined error**
- This does not happen if my arrow function points
  directly to the API function I'm calling (just omitting the {} for the return block fixes the bug? Why?)
- Is there some kind of
  variable scoping issue going on here that I'm not aware of?

**The function that I call on the class instance:**
`bar.doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword.then(auth => {console.log(auth)}`

**WORKS AS EXPECTED:**

```
class Foo extends Component{
  constructor() {this.auth = firebase.app.auth}
...
  doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) => 
    this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
```

**TYPE ERROR:UNDEFINED:**

```
class Foo extends Component{
  constructor() {this.auth = firebase.app.auth}
...
  doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) => {
    this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  }
```

Comment: What *exactly* is the error?

Comment: You should `return this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` with `{}`.

Comment: `doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword` doesn't return anything when you use `{}`.  A bare `() => something` automatically returns the "body" of the bare arrow function.  Using `{}` means you have to do it explicitly.

Comment: Because without the `{}` javascript automatically inserts `return` before your code. But with the `{}` it does not insert a `return` keyword so you have to insert it yourself. So something like `(x, y) => foo()` is the same as `(x, y) => {return foo()}`

Comment: Thanks! I feel really silly that this bug caused me an hour of headache because I forgot that there is no implicit return in { } arrow block.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [When should I use `return` in es6 Arrow Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28889450/691711).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

With an one-line arrow function (no braces) the return is implicit. As soon as you add braces, you need to add the return statement, like this:

```
class Foo extends Component{
  constructor() {this.auth = firebase.app.auth}
...
  doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) => {
    return this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  }
```