# How to define variables in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

currently i have this working code..

```
const HomePage = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="page-home">
      {
        Object.keys(props.data).map(key => (
          <section key={key}>
            <Link to={props.data[key].route}>{props.data[key].title}</Link>
            <Categories collections={props.data[key].collections} />
          </section>
        ))
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

however, i want to use a variable to make the code more readable, but it throws an error `Parsing error: Unexpected reserved word 'let'`

```
const HomePage = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="page-home">
      {
        Object.keys(props.data).map(key => (

          // this is the var defintion that causes the problem
          let obj = props.data[key]

          <section key={key}>
            <Link to={obj.route}>{obj.title}</Link>
            <Categories collections={obj.collections} />
          </section>
        ))
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

can someone explain why this is happening, and what the correct way to do this would be?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use \`return\` in es6 Arrow Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-return-in-es6-arrow-functions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Can only put valid [JavaScript expression inside the curly braces in JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx)
so `{let arr=[]}` is invalid since it is not an [Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Expressions)
but you can do declaration inside a regular `{ .. }` javascript code block;

```
const HomePage = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="page-home">
      {
        Object.keys(props.data).map(key => {
          /*
          this is regular JS function body; even-though it is inside JSX but its body of 
          map's callback function so you can put any js code here 
          */

          let obj = props.data[key]
          return (<section key={key}>
            <Link to={obj.route}>{obj.title}</Link>
            <Categories collections={obj.collections} />
          </section>)
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

but what was the problem in your code? you were declaring a variable inside group operator [( )](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) and again variable declaration isn't an Expression ([check all the Operators in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators)) hence the compiler yells at you.

```js
console.log((1==2)) //no problem valid expression
console.log((1)) //no problem valid expression
console.log((1*2)) //no problem valid expression
console.log((function a(){ return 1}))  //no problem valid expression
```

```js
(const a = function(){ return 1})  //!!! problem not an expression
```

Answer (score 4):

You have a syntax issue, below code should work.

```js
const HomePage = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="page-home">
      {Object.keys(props.data).map(key => {

        // this is the added variable causing the issue
        const obj = props.data[key]

        return (
          <section key={key}>
            <Link to={obj.route}>{obj.title}</Link>
            <Categories collections={obj.collections} />
          </section>
        );

      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: a return in a return?

Comment: To explain, your callback function uses implicit return to return the JSX element. You would need to set your callback to a multiline function to declare the variable `obj`.

Comment: yes. first return returns the component output. The 2nd return returns the values for the .map() loop function