# If you have a promise inside a promise, do you need two catch?

Tags: javascript, fetch, es6-promise

For example, making two calls with `fetch()` (second one inside the .then()), do you need two `.catch()` or only the outside one is enough?

I have tried to replicate but couldn't so far.

```
b = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Solving...');
    resolve('solved');
  }, 3000);
})
  .then(() => {
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('Rejecting...');
        reject('error');
      }, 1000);
    })
      .then(() => null)
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Catching error inside.');
        console.log(error);
      });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Catching error outside.');
    console.log(error);
  });
```

This works, but if I remove the inner `catch()` I get `Unhandled promise rejection` error

```
Solving...
Rejecting...
(node:73650) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error
(node:73650) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:73650) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Because you're not returning the promise in the first `then` block, attaching a `.catch` to it is correct. If you did return the promise then the outer `.catch` would handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the promise in `then` blocks to be able to `catch` them in one chain:

```
b = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     setTimeout(() => {
       console.log('Solving...');
       resolve('solved');
     }, 3000);
  })
  .then(() => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('Rejecting...');
        reject('error');
      }, 1000);
    });
  })
  .then(() => null)      // You can get rid of this if you don't have anything to do here
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Catching error outside.');
    console.log(error);
  });
```

This should also be the preferred way. Having nested chaining as you have in your code sample will make the code very hard to read.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to mimic `fetch('url', settings).then(response => response.json()).then(data => fetch('url/'+data.id))...` so in this case I am not returning anything, just doing something when the fetch with data I need is solved

Comment: You are returning promise (`data => fetch()` returns a promise) here as well. With arrow functions, you don't have to explicitly type `return` as that's implicit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-return-in-es6-arrow-functions

Comment: So, in my example, you can get rid of the braces and the `return`, and simply say `.then(() => new Promise(..)).catch(...)`

Comment: Yes sorry, I oversimplified it but I had a body there. I made a test putting bad url in the inner one and indeed unhandled promise came up

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

> No need to multiple catch(). if any error detected then goes to catch()