# Array.filter returns an empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to solve a Kata in codewars. The goal of the kata is:
Your goal in this kata is to implement a difference function, which subtracts one list from another and returns the result.

It should remove all values from list a, which are present in list b.

`arrayDiff([1,2],[1]) == [2]`
I decided to solve the problem using the array.filter method. when I run this code below it returns an empty array.

```
function arrayDiff(a, b) {

    let filtered = a.filter(inventa =>{
        b.filter(inventb =>{
            inventa !== inventb
        })
    })

    return filtered;
}

arrayDiff([1,2],[1])
```

i have tried researching what could possibly be the cause. i would love an explanation on why it does so.

PS: I am a beginner

Comment: None of your `.filter()` callbacks returns anything. This won't produce the requested result, but it would be a first step in the right direction.

Comment: You might want to read: [When should I use \`return\` in es6 Arrow Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28889450)

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
function arrayDiff(arr1, arr2){
  return arr1
    .filter(x => !arr2.includes(x))
    .concat(arr2.filter(x => !arr1.includes(x)));
}
```

#### Edit: Explanation

This Code is first filteringthe first Array, to remove all items that are in the second. Then the first Array is put together with the second Array, which is filtered to remove all Elements that are already in the first Array.

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: ok, i'm sorry and thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

One line answer:

```
const arrayDiff = (a, b) => a.filter(r => !b.includes(r));
```

Then `arrayDiff([1,2],[1])` gives `[2]`.

> It should remove all values from list a, which are present in list b.

It only works for this scenario, not the other way around.