# When can I remove the curly brackets of a function?

Tags: javascript

I'm shortening a function expression to an arrow function expression.

When can I remove the curly brackets of the function? Can you always or is there a rule when you're allowed?

I see on (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) it says you can drop curly brackets when you use just a single expression:
[image]

However, I understood the following to be 2 expressions, and the absence of curly brackets doesn't stop the function from running. It does still create an implicit return and just returns the first expression. Is this all I need to know about getting rid of curly brackets in arrow function expressions?

```js
f = () => x = 5 * 5; this;

console.log(f());
```

Comment: please show the function.

Comment: when you want to return something without making other actions with a data.

Comment: @demkovych could you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: Without brackets it's just shorthand for return. On the end it the same.

Answer (score 0):

On this example you need a square brackets because you need to do something in function body:

```
const data = {a: 1, b: 2};

const functionWithReturn = () => {
  const newData = {
    ...data,
    c: 3
  }

  return newData;
}
```

This is shortcut for return (which doing exactly the same as previous):

```
const functionShort = () => ({
    ...data,
    c: 3
})
```

The only difference that on the first example you can do something else inside function (like calling another function, make some data mutation...).

Comment: so in the first example, the assignment of the variable `newData` would be an example of data mutation? As you can see in my example, I assign a value to a variable and the function returns it fine..

Comment: this is just shortcut for function return.

Comment: My question was at what point in the shortening of a function expression can you remove the brackets. I've read somewhere you can remove brackets when there is a single line or single expression. I wasn't sure what these two concepts mean

Comment: It's just a language sugar. You choose where to use them. There are no strict rule about it.

Comment: Okay, that's good to know, thanks. And what do you mean by language sugar?

Comment: it's the same like `const a = () => {}` and `function a () {}`. Different ways to write the same.

Answer (score 0):

What I believe you are talking about is an implicit return.

If you remove the curly braces from an arrow function it is implied that you will return what ever the code tells it to do

```
let implicitAddFunc = (arg) => arg + 2;
```

In this example you do not need to explicitly declare what you are returning from the function. When you are using curly braces you must actually call out what you are returning

```
let nonImplicitAddFunc = (arg) => {
    let returnValue;
    returnValue = arg + 2
    //With curly brace must have the keyword *return*
    return returnValue
  }
```

For a deeper dive please reference this post [When should I use `return` in es6 Arrow Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-return-in-es6-arrow-functions)