# How to update an object property?

Tags: javascript

I have this array:

```js
let myArray = [
  {
    id: 20,
    comments: {
      TICOL: 'This is a new comment'
    },
    result: 'my results'
  }
];
```

Now I'm trying to update the TICOL property by first creating a copy of the array like this:

```js
let someArray = [...myArray];

let finalArray = someArray.map(obj => {
  obj.comments.TICOL = obj.comments.TICOL.replaceAll('new', 'TEST')
});
```

But finalArray is always `[undefined]`. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing? Thanks

Comment: [You never return anything from `.map()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28889450), hence why the array it returns has `undefined` in it - the implicit value of function calls.

Comment: You aren't returning anything. But why use map anyway? If you want to mutate, use a method for plain iteration like forEach

Comment: Also an important point; `[...myArray]` creates only a shallow copy.  Since the elements are objects, mutating their properties will affect both arrays.

Comment: Note that `[...myArray]` returns a shallow copy, elements in the second array are simply references the objects in the first array so modifying the objects in the first array also modifies those in the second (because they're the same objects).

Comment: @Taplar what will be another way to mutate my array?

Comment: You mean, how to do a deep copy?  `var someArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myArray));`

Comment: @Taplar thank you mate!

Comment: @Taplar—that has several issues that need to be explained, see [*What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript/122704#122704) and many similar questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return the new value within `map` method:

```js
let finalArray = someArray.map(obj => {
   obj.comments.TICOL = obj.comments.TICOL.replaceAll('new', 'TEST');
   return obj;
});
```