# Why is my JSON response returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, rest, fetch

I'm trying to make a fetch request for COVID data in my React Native app but each time I try to inspect the response, the console outputs undefined for the `json` variable:

```
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://api.covid19api.com/summary")
      .then((response) => {
        response.json();
      })
      .then((json) => {
        console.log("json.. " + json);
        setData(json);
      }) 
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first `.then()`, you are not returning anything, so `undefined` is returned implicitly.

You should return the `reponse.json()`:

```js
.then((response) => {
   return response.json();
})
```

Or shorter:

```js
.then((response) => response.json())
```

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-a-return-statement-in-es6-arrow-functions