# Why in the following code useEffect hook uses the curly braces, but without return statement, it still works?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, arrow-functions

after I read this article [When should I use a return statement in ES6 arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-a-return-statement-in-es6-arrow-functions), I'm still a little bit confused.Why the following code useEffect uses the curly braces, but without return it still works? Not sure if I  misunderstand something.
Here is the example:

```
import React,{useEffect,useState} from "react"

function App() {
  const [resourcetype,setresourcetype]=useState("posts")

  
  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("render")
  },[resourcetype])
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={()=>setresourcetype("try")}>try</button>
      <button onClick={()=>setresourcetype("unknown")}>unknown</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Like a function declaration or expression, the return statement for an arrow function with a block is optional. If you omit it then the function returns `undefined`

Comment: You mean it's not necessary to add return when using block in arrow function?And without return arrow function with block will still return a value which is undefined?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some information about the `useEffect` hook: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Essentially `useEffect` acts as `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount`. Those function are called by React during different parts of the component lifecycle, and do not need a `return` statement to work, as you can call functions without `return` statements similarly as you call functions with `return` statements.

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` is a React hook, lets you perform side effects in function components.
As per your sample code, this `useEffect` will run whenever `resourcetype` variable will change.
As per the documentation of `useEffect` it accepts a function as an argument and executes that function.
As per your sample code

```
 useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("render")
  },[resourcetype])
```

the function you have passed to `useEffect` is not returning anything, as per the documentation of `useEffect` if your function returns another function, that function will execute when your component unmounts.

```
 useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("Mounted")
    return () => { console.log("component unmounted")}
  },[])
```

> Bottom line is we don't want/need to return any value (string, number
> etc) from the function that we are passing to `useEffect` hook.

Comment: I remember when useEffect return another function that is used for clean up