# Cannot destructure property 'data' of '(intermediate value)' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This error is in the console and it prevents the app from working, I cant find the bug at all if anyone could help? Its a MERN application

The code in question

```
export const getPosts = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await api.fetchPosts();
  
      dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_ALL', payload: data });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  };
```

VSC is telling me await doesn't effect this kind of expression, which it should as fetchPosts is a request? The code for this is below

```
export const fetchPosts = () => {
    axios.get(url)
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use a return statement in ES6 arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-a-return-statement-in-es6-arrow-functions)

Comment: Thank you for the help

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem is that, although [`axios.get`](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosgeturl-config) may return a promise, the `fetchPosts` function you've wrapped it in doesn't return the promise that `axios.get` returns:

```js
const fetchPosts = () => {
    axios.get(url);
};

const myFetch = fetchPosts();

console.log(myFetch); // will log `undefined`
```

If you rewrite `fetchPosts` as so:

```js
export const fetchPosts = () => axios.get(url);
```

...with the [implicit return from your arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#function_body), I think it should work.  Alternatively, you could just explicitly return the result of `axios.get`:

```js
const fetchPosts = () => {
    return axios.get(url);
};
```

...but your linter *may* complain about that.

Comment: amazing, thank you, this has been driving me crazy for two hours! Not that i would but would setting const info = axios.get(url) and then return info have the same effect? Much better as one line just trying to understand the JS behind it more?

Comment: @DanWilstrop yes, that would also work. You basically need to return a promise. Does not matter what else you do in the function.

Answer (score 0):

let's try to return a Promise from the function, that use axios:

```
export const fetchPosts = async () => return await axios.get(url);
```

And then you can use destructuring at `then`-block of handling Promise

```
export const getPosts = async dispatch => {
  await fetchPosts()
    .then({data}) => dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_ALL', payload: data)
    .catch(error => {console.log(error.message)});
}
```