# Ternary conditional works one time but not another javascript

Tags: javascript

**First of all this does not work for me, And I explain it so that they do not close the question, I am making two more or less equal algorithms with ternary conditional, simply one is an array of objects and the other an array of numbers, and with the numbers I don't have that problem, that's why What do I think is a problem with the code:**
[When should I use a return statement in ES6 arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-a-return-statement-in-es6-arrow-functions)

I'm new to the world of javascript and when doing a reduce for an array, I want to try to count the number of times the age is equal in an array of objects whose properties are the ages.

However when I do a ternary conditional I receive that the output is undefined.

but when doing a normal if with an else if you can do the count:
**Code:**
const numbers = [ {age: 4, age2: 4}, {age: 5, age2: 6}, {age: 88, age2: 99}, {age:14, age2:14}, {age: 2, age2: 2} ];

```
const getCount = ( objects ) => objects.reduce((acc, el) => {
    if ( el.age === el.age2 ) {
        return acc += 1;
    }
    else {
        return acc;
    }
}, 0);

const b = getCount(numbers)
console.log(b)
```

**Output:**

```
3
```

But with this Code:

```
const numbers = [ {age: 4, age2: 4}, {age: 5, age2: 6}, {age: 88, age2: 99}, {age:14, age2:14}, {age: 2, age2: 2} ];

    const getCount = ( objects ) => objects.reduce((acc, el) => {
        el.age === el.age2 ? acc += 1 : acc;
    }, 0);
    
    const b = getCount(numbers)
    console.log(b)
```

**Output**

```
undefined
```

**However, if I don't use objects and I only do the count if some element is repeated, with the same ternary conditional, this does work.**

```
const count2 = ( objects ) => objects.reduce( (acc, el) => el === 1 ? acc += 1 : acc )
console.log(count2( [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 4] ))
```

**Output**

```
3
```

Please I do not understand what happens, what is the error

Comment: Did you read the discussion in the link that you have added in your question?

Comment: It has long, comprehensive and beautiful conversation about `return` statement in arrow functions. Please read all the posts and comments in that question carefully, try those code snippets by yourself, and you won't face that problem again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgotten to return the accumulator value :

```
const getCount = ( objects ) => objects.reduce((acc, el) => {
      return el.age === el.age2 ? acc += 1 : acc;
    }, 0);
```

You can also remove the `{ }` and the keywork `return`

```
const getCount = ( objects ) => objects.reduce((acc, el) => el.age === el.age2 ? acc += 1 : acc, 0)
```

Comment: I can't believe I forgot that

Comment: @uriesputo It's not about forgetting. There are some places where `return` is implicit and some places where it is required. Please understand those concepts. I believe "they" had provided  the link for looking into before closing your previous question. Please don't blame anyone!

Answer (score 0):

Beside the missing `return` statement and using a block statement, you could simplifiy the function and just add the accumulator and the comparison value.

```
const getCount = objects => objects.reduce((acc, el) => acc + (el.age === el.age2), 0);
```