# How to turn a higher order "array function" into a higher order "regular function"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As I am learning react at the moment I came across this concept of event handler using "**setState**".

It is a little complicated for my understanding as 3 functions within each other. Case in point.

```
class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    };

this.increment = this.increment.bind(this)
    
increment(){
    this.setState(state => ({count: state.count+ 1}))
} 

//....some other code
```

This code works. I tried to understand the increment function a little further but I can't understand why the following code will not work:

```
increment(){
  this.setState(function anon(state){
    count: state.count+1
    })
}
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: the 2nd function has no return value

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski also missing second pair of `{` and `}` for object/function body.

Comment: Duplicate: [When should I use a return statement in ES6 arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-a-return-statement-in-es6-arrow-functions)

Answer (score 2):

```js
function anon(state) {
  count: state.count + 1
}
```

^ This function is neither creating an object, nor returning anything from the function. It is creating a [`label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) called `count` inside the function. So, it is not throwing a syntax error.

```js
this.setState(state => ({ count: state.count+ 1 }))
```

^ This callback creates an object with `count` key and implicitly returns it. It is equivalent to the following code when you use a *regular* function

```js
this.setState(function (state) => {
   return { count: state.count+ 1 }
})
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I forgot that arrow functions don't need the return syntax.

Comment: They do if they're inside curly brackets. Inside curly brackets the return must be explicit.

Answer (score 0):

The only missing part is `return`.

```
increment(){
  this.setState(function anon(state){
    return {count: state.count+1}
    })
}
```