# hiding/ revealing divs with useState?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, state, use-state

Beginner React developer here.

here is my state and function that toggles a ul from display:none to display:block

```
const [dropDown, setDropdown] = useState('hidden')
```

```
const [icon, setIcon] = useState('\u2795')
```

const handleHidden = () => {

```
if (dropDown === 'hidden') setDropdown('active')
if (dropDown === 'active') setDropdown('hidden')
if (icon === '\u2795') setIcon('\u2796')
if (icon === '\u2796') setIcon('\u2795')
```

}

the icons just toggle between a unicode "+" and "-"

and a corresponding onClick function to toggle between the two classes:

```
 <span onClick={() => handleHidden()} className='plus-minus'>{icon}</span></h3>
```

in addition to this code I map through an array of students and diplay all their values in a div.

The problem is when I click the span all the items open and close (expectedly). what would be the next steps to having only the item that I click open and close while the rest stay hidden?

Comment: Could you have a state variable `currentOpen` that keeps track of which index in the array is open and only show that one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a single index variable in state instead, which indicates the current open item. Something along the lines of

```
const [openIndex, setOpenIndex] = useState(-1); // none open initially
const makeHandleClick = i => () => {
  setOpenIndex(i === openIndex ? -1 : i);
};
// ...
return students.map((student, i) => (
  // ...
   <span onClick={makeHandleClick(i)} className='plus-minus'>
    {openIndex === i ? '\u2795' : '\u2796'}
  }</span>
```

To check whether a student item should be open or closed when rendering, check if `i === openIndex`. No need for the `icon` state variable as well.

Comment: There needs to be a slight modification. The onClick has to be a function,  which yours is not. So you need to change it to `onClick = {() => makeHandleClick(i)}`

Comment: It's a higher-order function so as to pass the `i` into the closure, which makes the syntax a bit easier. (See how `makeHandleClick` returns a function.) Should work as is, I think.

Comment: @sidc makeHandleClick will return a function. So it is okay

Comment: @invisal Yes, correct. I didn't notice that. Perhaps change makeHandleClick to be a regular function, and change the onClick to have an arraow function.

Comment: @sidc Why? The entire point of using a curried/higher-order function is to avoid the anonymous handler function.

Comment: @CertainPerformance worked like a charm thanks. Where can i read more about the syntax for the makeHandleClick function? why doesnt it work as 
makeHandleClick = (i) => {
//some code
}

Comment: @BenShekhtman It's a bit like currying. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-a-return-statement-in-es6-arrow-functions

Comment: @CertainPerformance
also how can i account for multiple items open at a time? when i open one another closes? Assuming the user would like to have more than one open at a time does setOpenIndex need to be coverted to an array to accept more than one possible value?