# Why my fetch function isn't working when i use standart function

Tags: javascript, function, fetch

Hello my problem is about function inside '.then' function. Why my standart function isn't working ? But when arrow function works. What is main difference between arrow function and standart function

```
fetch('cart/',{
    method:'post',
    headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'},
    body : JSON.stringify({'something':'something' })
 }) 

.then( res=> res.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Above code works .Also this is my approach

```
fetch('cart/',{
    method:'post',
    headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'},
    body : JSON.stringify({slug: g})
    })

.then( function (res){ res.json() )
        .then(function (res) { console.log(res) });
```

Comment: Did you miss an assignment on the first line?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**Describe the problem. "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough** to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question."_

Comment: Option 1 logs `data`. Option 2 does "nothing". What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @Andreas now I edited my real code and i found that the problem is that i didn't  write 'return ' before  'res.json() ' .So when I use arrow function does it automatically return variable  and i don't need to write return?

Comment: In your first version of the question there was `return res;`... Please spent more time with proofreading _before_ you post your question.

Comment: Duplicate of: [When should I use a return statement in ES6 arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-a-return-statement-in-es6-arrow-functions)

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because you need to return value:

```
.then(function (res) { return res.json() })
```

See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#function_body).

> Arrow functions can have either a "concise body" or the usual "block body".
>
> In a concise body, only an expression is specified, which becomes the implicit return value. In a block body, you must use an explicit return statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning res.json() in the standard function so there won't be anything going in the "then" block thats why it wont log