# Not understanding the second return statement in this function

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript and while I was on [Codewars](https://www.codewars.com/) I couldn't figure this problem out so I looked for a solution.

This is the solution I found and I just don't understand why there needs to be a second return statement inside the map method. If anyone could give me some insight it would be much appreciated. Thank you.

```
let spinWords = (str) => {
    return str.split(' ').map(function(string) {
        return (string.length > 4) ? string.split('').reverse().join('') : string 
    }).join(' ');
}
```

Comment: `.map()` is used to transform an array by passing source elements into a function and using the **returned** values from that function to build a new array. The "inner" `return` is for that `.map()` callback.

Comment: Please check the docs first: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#parameters (the second return returns from the anonymous inner function that is passed as first argument to the `map()` call) Here's a refactored version with the inner function moved outside: https://jsfiddle.net/x8fkydqw/

Answer (score 2):

The `.map` function accepts a callback, and that callback is a function that runs for every item in the array. For a simple example:

```js
const upperCase = str => str.toUpperCase();

console.log(
  ['a', 'b'].map(upperCase)
);
```

Above, it's called with both elements of the array: `upperCase('a')` and `upperCase('b')`, and the results are put into the new array, which is then `console.log`ged.

You can also define functions inline and pass that to `.map`:

```js
console.log(
  ['a', 'b'].map(str => str.toUpperCase())
);
```

Your code's original

```
str.split(' ').map(function(string) {
   return (string.length > 4) ? string.split('').reverse().join('') : string 
}).join(' ');
```

is doing the same sort of thing, except that

- the body of the function is more complicated, and
- it's using the `function` keyword, rather than an arrow function, and thus needs the `return` keyword in order to return values ([unlike arrow functions in some circumstances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-a-return-statement-in-es6-arrow-functions)).

Answer (score 2):

The second return is a callback function. Try looking at it like this:

```js
function reverseWord(string) {
   return (string.length > 4) ? string.split('').reverse().join('') : string 
  }
let spinWords = (str) => {
    return str.split(' ').map(reverseWord).join(' ');
}
```

So `reverseWord` is your callback function, with its own return. The value it returns is the value used in the mapped array.