# Filtering an array based off of another objects values

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

**I'd like to filter this programs array** (I've simplified the objects):

```
const programs = [
      {
        format: "In-Person",
        schedule: "Full-Time",
      },
      {
        format: "Remote",
        schedule: "Full-Time",
      },
      {
        format: "In-Person",
        schedule: "Part-Time",
      },
      {
        format: "Remote",
        schedule: "Part-Time",
      }
    ]
```

**based on a filter object:**

```
const filters = {format: "Remote", schedule:"Full-Time"}
```

My attempt:

```
  let filteredPrograms = programs.filter((program) => {
    return Object.entries(filters).every(([key, value]) => {
      program[key] == value;
    });
  });
```

This should analyze each program, and allow is to pass through the filter IF:
For every filter key, the program[filter key] value matches the filter value

But I'm getting an empty array for filteredPrograms

Comment: but actually this is the problem: [When should I use a return statement in ES6 arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-a-return-statement-in-es6-arrow-functions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return the comparison result inside the `every` callback:

```js
const programs=[{format:"In-Person",schedule:"Full-Time"},{format:"Remote",schedule:"Full-Time"},{format:"In-Person",schedule:"Part-Time"},{format:"Remote",schedule:"Part-Time"}],filters={format:"Remote",schedule:"Full-Time"};

let filteredPrograms = programs.filter((program) => {
  return Object.entries(filters).every(([key, value]) => {
    return program[key] == value;
  });
});
console.log(filteredPrograms)
```

Or make it an arrow function:

```js
const programs=[{format:"In-Person",schedule:"Full-Time"},{format:"Remote",schedule:"Full-Time"},{format:"In-Person",schedule:"Part-Time"},{format:"Remote",schedule:"Part-Time"}],filters={format:"Remote",schedule:"Full-Time"};

let filteredPrograms = programs.filter((program) => {
  return Object.entries(filters).every(([key, value]) => program[key] == value);
});
console.log(filteredPrograms)
```

Comment: wow lol spent 3 hours on that and the docs for .every top example didn't show a return so I didn't even think of it. Thanks

Comment: This is a duplicate twice over, both the actual question and the syntax error. (also both of your snippets use arrow functions, but the second uses an implicit return)