# How to render components this way

Tags: reactjs, react-native, rendering

I'm watching v5 tutorial and there is

```
const HomeStack = () => {
  <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Settings">
      {(props) => <Text>Profile's settings</Text>}
    </Stack.Screen>
  </Stack.Navigator>;
};
```

but it's not working for me. I want to render  *`<Text>Profile's settings</Text>`*

I get this error [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvIbc.png)

What is the correct way of doing it and what is called?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use a return statement in ES6 arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-a-return-statement-in-es6-arrow-functions)

Answer (score 1):

your function should to return jsx

```
  const HomeStack = () => {
    return(
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Settings">
          {(props) => <Text>Profile's settings</Text>}
        </Stack.Screen>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    )
  };
```