# Setting state from an API call inside a useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, asynchronous

I am trying to set the state from an async API call and then dynamically render some JSX based on the returned data.

The problem is, I think the state is being set only after the JSX has already rendered, and since it is in an a useEffect hook with a dependency( "[]" ) it only renders on the initial load. Therefore, the `map` in the JSX does not run.

I know the API is returning the correct data, as I can tell from the `console.log` but not sure where to go from here? I've tried adding the `workspaces` variable as a dependency to the useEffect hook but that just causes an infinite loop. Any ideas?

```
export const WorkspaceToggle = () => {
 
    const [workspaces, setWorkspaces] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {

      (async () => {
        
        const data = await getUserWorkspaces()
        setWorkspaces(data)
        console.log(data)
        
      })();

    }, []);
    
    return (
      <>
        <Container>
          <DropdownCon>
            <DropdownToggle>{dropdownText}</DropdownToggle>
            <DropdownMenu>
              
              {workspaces.map((space: any) => {
                
                <DropdownItem eventKey="1">{space.name} Workspace</DropdownItem>
                
              }) as ReactNode}
              
            </DropdownMenu>
          </DropdownCon>
        </Container>
      </>
    )
  }
```

Comment: `forEach()` doesn't return anything, use `map()` instead... `{workspaces.map(({ name }) => <DropdownItem eventKey="1">{name} Workspace</DropdownItem>)}`

Comment: Your `map()` callback isn't returning anything. See [When should I use a return statement in ES6 arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28889450/283366)

Comment: @Phil just tried that, no luck :(

Comment: @Phil thank you for pointing the out, that was indeed all I was missing and it is now working. Bonehead mistake, thank you