# How can i display different component in map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a `Card` component and a `QuestionCard` component.

what I want to do is when a user uploads a post or asks a question, it shows the respective component. And this is my idea of doing it :

```
const CardList = ({cardList}) => {
  return (
    <div className="cardWrapper">
      <div className="cardColumn">
        {cardList.map((card)=>{
            if(){ 
                <Card />
            } else{
                <QuestionCard />
            }
        })}
      </div>
```

but I don't know what to fill in the expression. Am I have the right idea? Or there are some other ways to do it?

Here is some reference how what it should look like:

[reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQuZQ.jpg)

Comment: you forgot to return the <Card /> and <QuestionCard />

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use a return statement in ES6 arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-a-return-statement-in-es6-arrow-functions)

Comment: @Dilshan thanks for reminding me but what I'm asking is what condition should I put inside the parenthesis to accomplish what I want. Sorry if I describe the wrong situation

Comment: Since you haven't given any information about what the data for each card contains we can't tell what the condition would be. What in the card data distinguishes a `Card` from a `QuestionCard`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you return the component to be rendered inside `map`.

```
if (){ 
    return <Card / > ;
}
```

```
else {
    return <QuestionCard / > ;
}
```

Comment: what condition should I put inside the parenthesis if I want to return the respective component? For instance, if the user uploads a post then return the `card` component, and if the user asks a question then return the `question` component. All I can think of is using the `useState` hook.

Comment: It depends on what property you are using to classify the "uploads" as you call them. For instance, if you have a type property then it'd be something like ```if (card.type === "question") { return <QuestionCard /> } else { return <Card />}```

Comment: Sorry, I have a super newbie question, how or where do I define the `card.type`? Inside my `Card` component or inside the `cardList` component?

Comment: It would make sense to define it on ```Card```. This is because you have to have a way of differentiating the different types of input (question or post). Logically, it would make sense to use ```CardList``` for rendering multiple ```Card```s.

Comment: Sorry to bother u, but how do I define the type of component? `function Card (): card {}`? but this is for typescript

Comment: If you can, please share a Pastebin link to your component. It'll be much easier to explain using your own code, otherwise I feel like I might be confusing you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

- If a question is asked by the user — we wish to render `<QuestionCard />`;
- If a post is uploaded by the user — we wish to render `<Card />`.

First off, you need a way to determine if the looped-over object is a ***question*** or a ***post***:

One way of doing so is adding 1 or 2 `boolean` properties to your `cardList` array of objects:

1. `isQuestion` — if set to `true` then the card is a question;
2. `isPost` — if set to `true` then the card is an uploaded post.

In fact, one of the two is plenty enough for this use case.

`card.isQuestion ? (Render <QuestionCard/>) : (Render <Card />)`

I am using a ternary operator because it is easier to read than an `if` statement.

Provided that's what you want to do, your test would look like this:

```
{cardList.map((card, id) =>
            card.isPost ? ( // Render <Card /> if the card is a post
             <Card key={id} />
            ) : ( // If the card isn't an uploaded post then it is necessarily a question
              <QuestionCard key={id} />
            )
          )}
```

**P.S.** You should probably use [NextJS' dynamic styling system](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#adding-component-level-css) depending on how much your project is going to scale, to avoid any mix-ups between the same classname in different files in the future.