# Why does Javascript map() render my feature where forEach() didn't? Using React with NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, use-state

I had an issue where my feature wasn't rendering because I don't think React understood the state was changing.  After changing the `forEach()` to `map()`, the feature rendered as expected.

Feature will take user's subscriptions from an API then render as list. This is the final working version.

```js
...
export default function MyComp() {
  const [userSubIds, setUserSubIds] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    getSubs().then(p => setUserSubIds(p))
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
    {
      userSubIds?.map(subId => {
        <ListItem>
          {subId.data}
        </ListItem>
      })
    }
    </>
  )
```

Previously I had used `forEach()`.  This did not return any error nor any feature on the web page.

```js
...
      userSubIds?.forEach(subId => {
        <ListItem>
          {subId.data}
        </ListItem>
      })
...
```

From reading the docs, `forEach()` always returns `undefined` and `map()` returns a new array.  But what I'm missing in knowledge is why this matters for rendering?

Comment: Neither one returns anything here, although `forEach` is clearly inappropriate because of the fact that it returns undef, which tells JSX not to render anything. If you're using `map` with brackets, use `return`, or change the brackets to `()`s to make it return the result of an expression (invoking `React.createElement` via JSX syntactical sugar in this case). I'm surprised your "final working version" works as you claim.

Comment: As you have stated, `forEach` returns `undefied`, so there is nothing to render.

Comment: and [When should I use a return statement in ES6 arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-a-return-statement-in-es6-arrow-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, your loop has to return elements. Those elements will go into your tags and thus it will be rendered.

Now, `map` returns an array of the same size with the modified elements.
`forEach` does not return anything. It is just traversing the array. It does not give react the elements that it needs.

```
<>
{
  userSubIds?.map(subId => 
    <ListItem>
      {subId.data}
    </ListItem>
  )
}
<>
// This has returned elements like this
<ListItem> some data </ListItem>
<ListItem> some data </ListItem>
<ListItem> some data </ListItem>
...
```

However, `forEach` has not returned any data.

```
userSubIds?.forEach(subId =>
  <ListItem>
    {subId.data}
  </ListItem>
})
// This has returned nothing.
```

Comment: See my [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73008284/why-does-javascript-map-render-my-feature-where-foreach-didnt-using-react#comment128946996_73008284). `map` with braces and no `return` doesn't return anything. OP's code is in a confused state and needs to be clarified, because what they claim works can't possibly.

Comment: I see that, thanks, but it's a subtle change that should be clarified in text. Your `forEach` has a loose brace.

Comment: @ggorlen hey sure!! Your edits to my answer are always welcomed and very much appreciated. Thanks!