# React - Array of elements no rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I'm trying to make a multiple choice quiz game. In this component I am rendering a paragraph with the body of the question and I also want to render an array of list elements which will be all the possible answers. The problem I'm having is that the list of answers is not rendering... Here is my code

```
function Question(props) {  
 const [answers, setAnswers] = React.useState(props.answers);

    return (
        <div>
            <p>{props.question}</p>
            {answers.map(el => {
                <li>{el}</li>
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Question
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use a return statement in ES6 arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-a-return-statement-in-es6-arrow-functions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while doing forEach, filter, map or etc. You need to return the HTML element to render. So in your case, it's not returned so it's not rendering.

```
 return (
        <div>
            <p>{props.question}</p>
            {answers.map(el => {
               return <li>{el}</li>
            })}
        </div>
    )
```

Comment: This solved it ... soo stupid of me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the element from function

```
function Question(props) {  
 const [answers, setAnswers] = React.useState(props.answers);

    return (
        <div>
            <p>{props.question}</p>
            {answers.map(el => {
               return <li>{el}</li>
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Question
```

or directly pass without {} like below

```
function Question(props) {  
     const [answers, setAnswers] = React.useState(props.answers);
    
        return (
            <div>
                <p>{props.question}</p>
                {answers.map(el => <li>{el}</li>)}
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    export default Question
```