# Don't get text back from HTTP fetch request with status 200

Tags: php, reactjs, apache

I'm new to react and try to send a request to my local apache server (run via xampp).

```js
fetch('http://localhost:80', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Accept': 'text/*'}    
}).then(
    (response) => {response.text();}
).then(
    (msg) => {console.log(msg)}
).then(
    (error) => {console.log(error)}
);
```

The response returns the status code 200. The php script writes to a text file and echos Hello World.

```php
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000');
$FILE = fopen("test.txt", "w");
fwrite($FILE, "Hello World");
?>
Hello World!
```

After executing the fetch, the console contains `[undefined]` twice. I previously logged the response, which contains an empty text attribute (and an empty json attribute), as well as status code 200 (Success). Also, the text-file is created, so the php-script definitely runs.

How can I see Hello World?

Comment: What do you see when you open `http://localhost` directly in your browser?

Comment: the `undefined` is coming from your last two `then`s. You need to use `catch` in-place of the last `then` to catch any errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to return response from the response.text() section..

```
}).then(
    (response) => { return response.text();}
).
```

or simply

```
}).then(
    (response) =>   response.text();
).
```

and also in error section use .catch instead of .then

Comment: Ah, so my mistake was I combined both solutions, which creates a void function?

Comment: yes ..  i believe this would help u... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-a-return-statement-in-es6-arrow-functions