# Is there a way of rendering React component iteratively?

Tags: reactjs, react-component

This problem involves two components:

- `<Grid/>`
- `<Cell/>`

A *Grid* is made out of *Cell*'s. I'm trying to display the cells that are in a list.

**What I've tried**

- In Grid.js

```
//Create a list of cells
let cells = [
    <Cell />,
    <Cell />,
];

//Render in the return
<div>
    {
        cells.map((cell) => {
            <Cell />
        })
    }
</div>
```

- In the *Cell.js*

```
//Just the instantiation with some sample text to print
import React from 'react'

const Cell = () => {
  return (
    <div>Cell</div>
  )
}

export default Cell
```

**The Result I'm getting**

Nothing is being displayed in the screen (nor errors in the console).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use a return statement in ES6 arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-a-return-statement-in-es6-arrow-functions)

Comment: It's essentially a typo.  The callback function to `.map()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @David yep! that was it, I was missing the return. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div>
    {
        cells.map((cell) => <Cell/>)
    }
</div>
```

or

```
<div>
    {
        cells.map((cell) => {
            return <Cell />
        })
    }
</div>
```

Comment: That was it! I'm very new to react so I missed the return . I got confused as I already had one outside (the main return)