# TypeError: undefined is not an object error on adding user input into ReactNative state array

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

I wish to add user-input text into a `state` array using ReactNative.

However, I get an error after I click the `button` inside my simulator.

Below is my `App.js`:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View, ScrollView } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {

  const [enteredGoalText, setEnteredGoalText] = useState('');
  const [userGoals, setUserGoals] = useState([]);

  function addGoalHandler() {
    setUserGoals((currentUserGoals) => {
       [...currentUserGoals, enteredGoalText,]
    })
  };

  function goalInputHandler(enteredText) {
    setEnteredGoalText(enteredText);
  };


  return (
    <View style={
      styles.appContainer}>
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
          <TextInput style={styles.textInput}
          placeholder = "Enter your goal"
          onChangeText={goalInputHandler}>
          </TextInput>
          <Button title="Add Goal" onPress={addGoalHandler}/>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.goalContainer} >
        <ScrollView>
          {userGoals.map((goal, index) => {
            return (
              <View style={styles.goalItem} key={index}>
                <Text style={styles.goalText} >{goal}</Text>
              </View>
            )
          })}
          </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  appContainer: {
    paddingTop: 50,
    paddingHorizontal: 16,
    borderWidth: 5,
    flex : 1,
    
  },
  inputContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row", 
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingBottom: 24,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: 'gray',
  },
  textInput: {
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderWidth: 1,
    width: '70%',
    marginRight: 8,
    padding: 8
  }, 
  goalContainer: {
    flex: 8
  },
  goalItem: {
    margin: 8,
    padding: 8,
    borderRadius: 6,
    backgroundColor: 'purple'
  },
  goalText: {
    color: 'white'
  }
});
```

On adding text and clicking on the `Add Goal` button, I encountered the below error -

```
This error is located at:
    in App (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent)
 ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'userGoals.map')
```

Comment: it `addGoalHandler` you need to add `return` before `[...currentUserGoals, enteredGoalText,]`. (Or alternatively remove the `{...}` around it)

Comment: not exactly a duplicate, but strongly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-a-return-statement-in-es6-arrow-functions

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link @RobinZigmond. Replacing with a `(` call solves it for me.