# How to send and receive props as an Object in react js fucntional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-props

I have a data like below

```
export const DataShirts = [
    {
        type:"tshirt",
        brand:"Levis"
    },
    {
        type:"tshirt",
        brand:"Duke"
    }
]
```

I am trying to send props in Home.js

```
{ data && data.length > 0 ? data?.map((item,index) => {
    return <Grid key={index} item xs={6} md={3}> <ProductCard item={item} /> </Grid>}) : null}
```

in ProductCard.js component file

```
const ProductCard = ({item}) => {
    
    console.log(item.brand)   // it's return undefined at second render
    return (
        <>

        </>
    )
}
```

what is the mistake here.

After Update the code

[image]

At first time, the output is correct, but second time it is showing undefined.

Why it render second time?

Comment: It should work (though not how you expect) based on what you've pasted. You can just `DataShirts.map`, you don't need `Object.values()`. Additionally, you're passing the whole item as the `brand` prop, so `brand` should log the full object and `type` would be undefined.

Comment: you need to `return <ProductCard brand={item} />` in your `map` function - you are not `return`ing anything at the moment so nothing will get rendered.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use a return statement in ES6 arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-a-return-statement-in-es6-arrow-functions)

Comment: since u are passing the object as `brand` what you are getting on the side as `props` will look something like `props = {brand:{...}}` so you need `{brand} = props`. now brand is a object which has the properties `brand` and `type`. so `console.log(brand.brand)` and `brand.type`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- first just use `map`, you don't need `Object.values`.
- also you don't return the component in the `map` function, so you're basically returning `undefined` for each entry.
- You must provide a unique `key` prop to the `ProductCard` component in the `map` callback, or React will have issues to update the components (adding a unique `_id` field to the data would be nice).
- you're passing the whole `item` object as `brand prop`, so `type` will be undefined.

to summarize, with the data :

```js
{DataShirts.map((item) => <ProductCard key={item.brand + item.type} item={item} />)}

const ProductCard = ({ item }) => {
    console.log(item.brand) // will print the brand
    return (<></>)
}
```

Comment: what if I have more than one line in my map return

Comment: @Liamneesan what do you mean ? The map must return an array of React Components. If you have a multi Line Component you can do :
`(item) => (<Component key={...}>...sub components
</Component>))`

Comment: @Liamneesan then use `DataShirts.map((item) => {//do stuff and finally return <ProductCard key={item.brand + item.type} item={item} />})`

Comment: @NathanSchwarz it's rendering 2 times, first time render i got the result in console log. second time item.brand is undefined error.

Comment: @Liamneesan this is not related to the code you provided but either to the data source / hooks you're using on the data. Please provide a full example.

Comment: @NathanSchwarz i found, thats my silly mistake. map function is working fine. I call the <ProductCard /> in another place without passing props, it expects props. so sad. I wasted a long time.