# I'm using Lodash forEach to set a boolean property but only the first object is affected

Tags: javascript, angular, lodash

I was trying to set a boolean property for every object of an array.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import * as _ from "lodash";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = "CodeSandbox";

  colors: {hex: string, used: boolean}[] = [
    {hex: "#ff0000", used: true},
    {hex: "#00ff00", used: true},
    {hex: "#0000ff", used: true}
  ]

  ngOnInit() {
    _.forEach(this.colors, c => c.used = false);
    console.log(this.colors);
  }
}
```

Apparently only the first object is affected. This is the output.

```
0: Object
hex: "#ff0000"
used: false
1: Object
hex: "#00ff00"
used: true
2: Object
hex: "#0000ff"
used: true
```

Here is the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-water-p19ihj?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

It works with _.map and with native forEach. Am I missing something or is it a bug?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you use lodash over the built-in array functions?

Comment: @BerkKurkcuoglu Mmmh I'd say team habit. Probably not the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#forEach) indicates that you can exit the `_.forEach()` early by explicitly returning `false` which your arrow function does via an implicit return.

> Iterates over elements of collection and invokes iteratee for each element. The iteratee is invoked with three arguments: (value, index|key, collection). **Iteratee functions may exit iteration early by explicitly returning false.**

Because you have not enclosed the body of your arrow function it implicitly returns the evaluated value of the body; `c.used = false` evaluates to `false` which is then returned and exits the `forEach`.

Surrounding the body with braces will avoid the arrow function's implicit return (it will now return `undefined` as any function with no return statement would) and thus allow the `forEach` to complete as expected.

```
_.forEach(this.colors, c => {c.used = false});
```

see: [When should I use a return statement in ES6 arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-a-return-statement-in-es6-arrow-functions) for discussion of returning from an arrow function.

Answer (score -1):

The _.forEach() method only iterates over own enumerable string keyed properties of an object.
The used property is not an own enumerable string keyed property of the objects in your colors array, but rather an enumerable property inherited from the Object prototype and in lodash version 4, only the first object is affected when you use _.forEach().

Comment: Tried renaming "used" with many (bizzarre) alternatives and still didn't work.