What is the difference between below two different ways of writing the react code
I recently started exploring react, functional components, fat arrow syntax, anonymous functions, redux, store, state, props, mapping and wondering what the difference between these two syntaxes is below and why the syntax #2 is preferred in React to write mapStateToProps, also what actually is Syntax #2
Syntax 1
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { outputProp: state.output }
}

Syntax 2
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  outputProp: state.output
})

state.output  is nothing but simple member of simple component's state and mapStateToProps will be exported default with the help of concept of HOC given below
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SomeFunctionalComponent)


Not actually @TusharShahi
if you see, both of the syntaxes have fat arrow I am more interested in knowing why one syntax has round braces () after fat arrow and one has curly braces {}.

Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-a-return-statement-in-es6-arrow-functions
I am assuming this should be a common question. That is just another syntax which you can use when there is no real logic inside the function body and just a return statement

Both are equal, but both are also using an extremely outdated (over half a decade) style of Redux. Please don't use connect in newly written React/Redux code, but use the useDispatch and useSelector hooks instead.
More on modern Redux: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts


One is just a short-hand version of the other.
Think of it like this:
const meaningOfLife = () => {return 42;}

vs:
const meaningOfLife = () => 42

The second example is just a shorthand version of the first.
In the second example, instead of a function body, it's just an an expression. The runtime implicitly inserts the {return ...} around the expression. So if your calculation for what to return can be simplified to a single expression, you can just use the simplified version.
Now you might think that you can avoid the parentheses ala:
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {outputProp: state.output}
The above won't work because now Javascript will think that the { curly brace is the start of a function body. The parentheses around the object clarifies it's an expression, not a function body.
