# Why can I not use `new` with an arrow function in JavaScript/ES6?

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

As far as I know, the arrow function is similar to a normal function. There aren’t any problem when I use it like this:

```js
let X = () => {};
let Y = function() {};
X();
Y();
```

However, the error occurred when I used them with `new`:

```js
let X = () => {};
let Y = function() {};
x = new X();
y = new Y();
```

`Uncaught TypeError: X is not a constructor`

Why is that?

Comment: The error itself gives you an answer.... you defined X to be an empty object, not a constructor method/function, as such you cannot invoke it with the "new X();" expression.

Comment: hmm, I see. But I wonder why `new Y()` does not cause error. Maybe JS do some magic things with function, not arrow function ?

Comment: Two possibilities: 1. ) Because your Y is a function, an empty one at that, though still defined as a function. 2) Because the code breaks and y = new Y(); is never run. You cannot get the object returned from the arrow functions as they give you now "this" to return

Comment: Because you can't as the documentation says.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939130/when-should-i-use-arrow-functions-in-ecmascript-6) may help you

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch.

Comment: @torazaburo That's a better duplicate target.

Comment: @torazaburo both questions you provided are rather canonical and don't answer the specific question of the OP in my view

Comment: @Iven Well, it's a canonical question. If you disagree with closing it against those dups, then vote to re-open. Both questions seem to quite clearly indicate that arrow functions are not constructors.

Comment: Arrow functions cannot be used as constructors as stated in the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: "Why can't I use 'new' with arrow functions?" is a completely different question from "Can someone give me a guide to arrow functions and when to use them?" I don't think we should be closing all useful narrow questions as duplicates of a big large broad general question.

Answer (score 30):

***Q.** What did I do wrong?*

**A.** You used `new` with an arrow function, and that's not allowed.

***Q.** Can I turn an arrow function into a constructor?*

**A.** Only by wrapping it in a normal function, which would be silly.
You can't turn an arrow function itself into a constructor.

***Q.** Can you explain how the specification disallows `new` with arrow functions?*

**A.** To be a constructor, a function object must have
a [`[[Construct]]`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#table-6)
internal method.

Functions created with the `function`
keyword are constructors, as are some built-in functions
such as `Date`. These are the functions you can use with `new`.

Other function objects do not have a `[[Construct]]`
internal method. These include arrow functions. So you can't
use `new` with these. This makes sense since you [can't set
the `this` value of an arrow function](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation).

Some built-in functions are also not constructors. E.g. you
can't do `new parseInt()`.

***Q.** Can you explain the rationale behind disallowing `new`
with arrow functions in the specification?*

**A.** Use common sense, or search the [es-discuss archives](https://esdiscuss.org/).

Comment: @Ricky I deleted my answer, because [`new` doesn't depend on the constructor's prototype](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinarycreatefromconstructor). Since you can't set `this` of arrows with `apply` or `bind`, it is consistent behavior to prohibit the application of `new` too. This is the best answer.

Answer (score 12):

Arrow functions are not synonymous with normal functions. `arguments` and `this` inside arrow functions reference their outer function.

When the code `new Foo(...)` is executed, the following things happen:

1. A new object is created, inheriting from Foo.prototype.
2. The constructor function Foo is called with the specified arguments, and
   with this bound to the newly created object. new Foo is equivalent
   to new Foo(), i.e. if no argument list is specified, Foo is called
   without arguments.
3. The object returned by the constructor function
   becomes the result of the whole new expression. If the constructor
   function doesn't explicitly return an object, the object created in
   step 1 is used instead. (Normally constructors don't return a value,
   but they can choose to do so if they want to override the normal
   object creation process.)

Since `this` inside an arrow function references its outer function (arrow functions inherit `this` from their declaration context, as @Iven is saying), using `new` keyword with an arrow function does not really make sense.

Comment: I have just read about it. But still don't understand why I can not create object like that

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question, which is why arrow functions do not function as constructors.

Comment: It is not that using `new` keyword with an arrow function "does not make sense". It is **illegal**.

Comment: Well, it's illegal *because* it doesn't make sense. Language designers don't make things illegal for the fun of it. So this does, in fact, answer the question.