# I am mocking a function instance(es5) using jest but not able to mock it properly

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

My code is as below ->

```
let mockFunction = jest.fn().mockImplementation((a) => {
    this.temp = a;
});
```

When I instantiate this function as follows

```
let mockFn = new mockFunction(6);
console.log(mockFn.temp) //this gives me undefined instead of 6
```

How can I access the instance in the mockImplementation function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrow functions are lexically scoped, so `this` won't refer to your `mockFunction` object.  You should change the callback to a regular function like so:

```
let mockFunction = jest.fn().mockImplementation(function(a) {
  this.temp = a;
});
```

Comment: To further explain, the arrow functions doesn't have a constructor so they cant be used with new. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37587834/javascript-es6-why-i-can-not-use-new-with-arrow-function