# angular 2 - Injected service in http error handler

Tags: angular, angular2-http, angular2-injection

I have a method handleError() like in the documentation https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#error-handling

```
private handleError(error: any) {
    console.error(error);
    console.log(this.loginService); // <- always undefined
    return Observable.throw(error);
}
```

My problem is, that **this.loginService** is **undefined** although it has been injected in my class correctly. It is already used in other methods but seems not to be available in **handleError**.

Could the way the method is called by the http-catch be the problem?
If so, how can i come around that? I need to execute some logic when handling an error.

This is an example on how i set handleError method as callback (exactly like documentation)

```
this.http.get(url,
              ApiRequest.ACCEPT_JSON)
              .map(ApiHelper.extractData)
              .catch(this.handleError);
```

Comment: Do you pass the `loginService` to the class constructor?

Comment: Yep. I am already using it in other methods in the same class.

Comment: Could you show us how you call `handleError` in your catch?

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since you're passing the function directly, you don't have the `this` context of your class in there. A really easy and best practice way would be to use a lambda or "fat arrow function":

```
this.http.get(url, ApiRequest.ACCEPT_JSON)
    .map(res => ApiHelper.extractData(res))
    .catch(err => this.handleError(err));
```

---

A really good read on when to use lambdas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23045200/1961059

Answer (score 5):

`this` in `handleError` in your case is probably not what you think it is.

Try to do the following:

```
this.http.get(url,
              ApiRequest.ACCEPT_JSON)
              .map(ApiHelper.extractData) 
              .catch(this.handleError.bind(this)); // <-- add .bind(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is also to assign your service to static variable of class

```
ClassToHandleError {
   private static loginService: LoginService;

   constructor(private loginService: LoginService) {
      ClassToHandleError.loginService = loginService;
   }

   private handleError(error: any) {
    console.error(error);
    console.log(ClassToHandleError.loginService); // here you can use static reference
    return Observable.throw(error);
   }
}
```

I know this is just workaround and rinukkusu provided definetely better solution then me. I used it until I get through this question. But maybe in some special case this will be valuable for somebody :) .