# Angular - use a service in a function and this function in a pipe

Tags: angular, service, scope, pipe, angular6

As written above, I want to use a Service, which is injected in root, in a function to logout the user after an 401 error. The function is called in a pipe after an error occured in one of my http requests. Unfortunately I get an error like: 
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'logout' of undefined 
after an 401 error. It seems like the function is called in a different scope. I tried to inject the Service via injector.get, to set my service and the error function to public but nothing worked. 
Is there any other opportunity to fix this?

```
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {}

private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
  if (error.status === 401) {
    this.authenticationService.logout();
  }
  return throwError('Something bad happened; please try again later.');
}

getSomething(): Observable<HttpResponse<Model>> {
  return this.httpClient.get<Model>(this.apiEndpoint, {
    observe: 'response'
  }).pipe(
  catchError(this.handleError)
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a `this` context issue. Either you can use fat arrow function or bind handleError function with service context.

```
getSomething(): Observable<HttpResponse<Model>> {
  return this.httpClient.get<Model>(this.apiEndpoint, {
    observe: 'response'
  }).pipe(
  catchError(this.handleError.bind(this))
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a working example it is a bit hard to troubleshoot, but I assume since you are passing the function directly, the function will not be executed in the `this` context of your class/component and therefore the service is probably undefined. A "fat arrow function" will most likely solve this problem.

Change your code like this:

```
getSomething(): Observable<HttpResponse<Model>> {
  return this.httpClient.get<Model>(this.apiEndpoint, {
    observe: 'response'
  }).pipe(
  catchError(err => this.handleError)
  );
}
```

Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37988781/angular-2-injected-service-in-http-error-handler) for more information.

Comment: unfortunately it doesnt work: Argument of type '(err: any) => (error: HttpErrorResponse) => Observable<never>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<JWToken>) => ObservableInput<{}>'
I'll try to build it on stackblitz