# TypeError: Cannot read property 'present' of undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, ionic2

I'm trying to call `loading/Toast/Alert` in `Ionic2` in the following scenario. As I'm new to  Ionic development, I am not able to figure it out. I am aware it's a silly error.

```
 var dg = document.getElementById('btnregis');
   dg.onclick =()=> this.presentLoading();


   presentLoading() {
    console.log("Registered");
    let loading = Loading.create({
        content: "Please wait...",
        duration: 3000
    });
    this.navController.present(loading);
    this.Reg_success();
}


    Reg_success() {
console.log("registration success");
        this.Billerlabelview = false;
        let toast = Toast.create({
            message: "Registering...",
            duration: 3000
        });
        this.navController.present(toast);
    }
```

The `reg_Success()` method is not getting called. It throws a similar exception. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Could you please add the rest of the code? That way we can take a look at which are the parameters in the constructor, and so other things that may be causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

where is the navController used? You can bind db.onclick method with this.

```
var dg = document.getElementById('btnregis');
 dg.onclick = this.presentLoading.bind(this);



   presentLoading() {
    console.log("Registered");
    let loading = Loading.create({
        content: "Please wait...",
        duration: 3000
    });
    this.navController.present(loading);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `this` context when just passing the reference to a function.

I'd advise you to use lambdas (or fat arrow function) wherever you're passing functions as parameters. Not only you have your `this` context from the right class/scope, but it is more readable and consistent.

```js
dg.onclick = () => this.presentLoading();
```

---

A really good read on when to use lambdas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23045200/1961059

Comment: Could you at least tell us, what exception you get?

Answer (score 0):

First, and because your're using the `present()` method from `NavController`, make sure you are defining it in your `constructor`:

```
class MyClass{
   constructor(navController: NavController) {
      // Ionic docs also recommends to add the next line to make it easier to understand http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/2.0.0-beta.9/api/components/nav/NavController/#present
      this.navController = navController;
   }    
}
```

Regarding your question, like you can see in [Ionic docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/2.0.0-beta.9/api/components/nav/NavController/#present) `present()` returns a `promise`, so you will have to wait until that gets resolved and *then* call your `Reg_success` method:

```
presentLoading() {
    console.log("Registered");
    let loading = Loading.create({
        content: "Please wait...",
        duration: 3000
    });
    this.navController.present(loading).then(() => {
        this.Reg_success();
    });        
}
```

Last but not least, you can also change the way you are handling the `click` event and instead of doing this:

`dg.onclick = this.presentLoading.bind(this);`

You can do it in the *ionic/angular2-way* by adding this code in your `button`:

`<button (click)="presentLoading()">Click me!</button>`