# A more efficiently/performant way to add elements and sort an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, data-manipulation

My function below returns an object containing the sorted `playerPoints` passed in via the "array of objects" parameter. Without modifying the passed in array, is there a more efficient/performant way to add elements and sort the array in ascending order?

**Note: The array of objects could contain one or more objects. In terms of efficiency, I'm referring to completion time (speed). Also the function, ascendingSort is required and can't be replaced.**

```js
var data = [{playerPoints: 10}, {playerPoints: 8}, {playerPoints: 2}, {playerPoints: 21},{playerPoints: 30}];

function ascendingSort(players) {
 var points = [];
 for(var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
  points.push(players[i].playerPoints);
 }
 points.sort(function(a, b) {return a - b;});
 return {sortedPoints: points};
}

var obj = ascendingSort(data);
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To simplify this function, you can use [the `map()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to map objects to `playerPoints` property. Also, you can change the regular function passed to the `sort()` method (`function(a, b) {return a - b;}`) to an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (`(a, b) => a - b`).

```js
const data = [{playerPoints: 10}, {playerPoints: 8}, {playerPoints: 2}, {playerPoints: 21},{playerPoints: 30}]

function ascendingSort(players) {
  return {
    sortedPoints: data.map(x => x.playerPoints).sort((a, b) => a - b)
  }
}

const obj = ascendingSort(data)
console.log(obj)
```

As for performance, I doubt there's a faster solution than that one you already have.

Comment: They can, but is it more efficient? The question isn't just asking for a different approach. What do the benchmarks show?

Comment: thanks for your lambda expression look a like method. Often see `map` method, but never see the implementation, up-voted :)

Comment: "you can change the regular function passed to the sort() method (function(a, b) {return a - b;}) to an arrow function " — Again, they can, but why should they? The primary reason for using an arrow function is that it affects the value of `this` … which isn't used in the function.

Comment: @Quentin I think that by "efficient" the OP meant "simpler", not "faster". Unless they're processing a lot of data, speed doesn't matter that much.

Comment: @Quentin "The primary reason for using an arrow function is that it affects the value of `this`" Not really, see [When should I use Arrow functions in ECMAScript 6?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22939130/3853934)

Comment: I edited my question to be more clearer. I have to use the function, ascendingSort to contain my logic and return an object containing the sorted points array.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just replace the function with

```
  function ascendingSort(players) {
      points.sort(function(a, b){return a["playerPoints"] - b["playerPoints"]});
      return {sortedPoints: players};
}
```